# How to find a object name by closest range value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my try:

```
var objects = [
  {"min":"0","max":"50","name":"name1"},
  {"min":"50","max":"100","name":"name2"},
  {"min":"100","max":"150","name":"name3"}
];

var value = 40;

objects.forEach(function(item, i){
    if(Number(item.min) >= value &&  value <= Number(item.max) ){
    console.log("name is ", item.name );
  }
});
```

getting console as :

```
name is  name2
name is  name3
```

but my expectation is `name is  name2` what is the correct way to get the range value with scenario?

Comment: What does "range value" mean?

Comment: @Liam between the min and max values

Comment: value = 40, lies between 0 to 50, console should print `name1`?

Comment: you're checking if 50 >= 40 &&  40<= 100 ... something's wrong here !

Comment: `>=` should be `<=` ... `min <= value && value <= max`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate an array based on supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: what is the result with `value = 500`? what means closest range in this case? or is it just insufficient wording?

Answer (score 2):

Move the `value` variable so that you're checking if it is greater or equal to the min, otherwise you're checking if the min is greater than or equal to `value`:-

```js
let objects = [
    {"min":"0","max":"50","name":"name1"},
    {"min":"50","max":"100","name":"name2"},
    {"min":"100","max":"150","name":"name3"}
];

let value = 40;

objects.forEach(function(item, i){
    if (value >= Number(item.min) && value <= Number(item.max)) {
        console.log("name is ", item.name );
    }
});
```

Comment: if I change value to 50, it gives 2 out puts.

Comment: yes it will...as you have `>=` and `<=` if you don't want the number included then remove the `=` so you only have greater than and less than.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#find` method:

```js
var objects = [
  {"min":"0","max":"50","name":"name1"},
  {"min":"50","max":"100","name":"name2"},
  {"min":"100","max":"150","name":"name3"}
];

var value = 90;

let res = objects.find(obj => Number(obj.min) <= value && value <= Number(obj.max));
console.log(res ? res.name : 'Not found');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, you just had to swap variables:

```
if(Number(item.min) >= value &&  value <= Number(item.max) ){
```

---

```
if(value >= Number(item.min) &&  value <= Number(item.max) ){
```

```js
var objects = [
  {"min":"0","max":"50","name":"name1"},
  {"min":"50","max":"100","name":"name2"},
  {"min":"100","max":"150","name":"name3"}
];

var value = 40;

objects.forEach(function(item, i){
    if(value >= Number(item.min) &&  value <= Number(item.max) ){
    console.log("name is ", item.name );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges increment by 50, you don't need to iterate at all. We just divide `value` by `50` and rounded down, giving us the index.

```
const index = n && Math.floor(n/50) - !(n%50);
```

Any range from `x1` to `x50` will be in the lower range, so values like `150` are handled. The `0` value is included in the first range.

```js
var objects = [
  {"min":"0","max":"50","name":"name1"},
  {"min":"50","max":"100","name":"name2"},
  {"min":"100","max":"150","name":"name3"}
];

test(0);
test(10);
test(50);
test(51);
test(100);
test(149);
test(150);
test(151);

function test(n) {
  const index = n && Math.floor(n/50) - !(n%50);
  const res = objects[index];
  console.log("value:", n, ", item:", res ? res.name : 'Not found');
}
```

Comment: @3gwebtrain: I added a new example that deals with numbers that land on a multiple of 50.