# Create a dynamic table in Angular based on the amount of rows chosen in a drop down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS 1.6 and I am trying to populate a table with rows depending on the amount of rows selected in a dropdown list. It could be anywhere from 1 to 12. So far I have the following code.

```
 <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <p>Blue Corner Boxer: </p> <input type="text" ng-model="nameBlue">
        <br>
        <p>Red Corner Boxer: </p> <input type="text" ng-model="nameRed">
        <br>
        <p>Number of Rounds:</p> <select ng-model="selectedRounds"><option ng-repeat="x in rounds">{{x}}</option></select>
    </div>

    <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameBlue}}</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">Round</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameRed}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="tablerows">
                       <tr ng-repeat="x in selectedRounds">
                           <td>Test</td>
                           <td>Test</td>
                           <td>Test</td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <h2 style="text-align: center">Final Score: </h2> {{scoreBlue1 + ScoreBlue2}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in the js file

```
//Create the module
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);



//Create the controller and register the module in one line
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "AngularJS tutorial";
    $scope.score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $scope.rounds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
});
```

So far the table will add 1 row on selection of anything 1 to 9, but 10 to 12 adds 2 rows. So I think I am wondering how to create an array length of size "selectedrounds" that will repeat rows with the repeater.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an array only for iterating and you don't worry about data in it. You can do something like this:

In your controller:

```
$scope.selectedRounds = 0;
$scope.getRoundsArray(){
   return new Array($scope.selectedRounds);
}
```

We just create an array with needed length and with all elements are 'undefined'. If you create an array with 3 lenght you will get: ['undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined'].

In view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in getRoundsArray() track by $index">
```

You need this track by $index cause your array contains only 'undefined' values so to prevent angular arguing about duplicate keys we need to use track by.

Comment: So if I do need to worry about the data in the rows afterwards, would I be better off not using ng-repeat and populating the table another way? I would need to do math on <Td> in rows 1 to x at the end of the table.

Comment: There is only one way to populate the table is by manipulating DOM by JavaScript or jQuery. I don't see any reason why not to use ng-repeat. If you need to worry about data you can create an array of needed length and populate data to it. You can use usual for loop or use _range function of lodash library.

https://lodash.com/docs#range

Comment: Also take a look at this discussion, maybe it help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/3710672