# Fastest way to fill an array with multiple value in JS. Can I pass a some pattern or function to method fill insted of a single value in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fill

Is it any way to create an array a selected size(for example 10) and immediately on the spot fill in it with some numbers specified pattern  (1, 2, 3, OR 2, 4, 6 and so on) in one statement in JS?

```js
let arr = new Array(10).fill( (a) => {a = 1; return a++; } );
console.log(arr); // Should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

In other words can I pass a some patern or function to method fill insted of a single value.

Comment: `Array.from(new Array(10), (_, i) => i) // [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`

Comment: **fastest** is `for` loop, and loop unrolling if possible https://esdiscuss.org/topic/typed-array-filling-convenience-and-performance

Comment: Array(10).fill(1).map((x, y) => x + y)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually there's much nicer idiom to create ranges: a spreaded `Array` constructor:

```
[...Array(n)]
```

creates an array of `n` undefined values. To get `0..n-1`, just pick its `keys`:

```
[...Array(n).keys()]
```

for arbitrary ranges, feed it to `map`:

```js
r = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => i + 1)

console.log(r)
```

see here: [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate an array based on supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl)

old answer:

yep, you're looking for [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
r = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(r)
```

How does this work? `.from` inspects its first argument (which can be any object) and picks its `.length` property. Then, it iterates from `0` to `length - 1` and invokes the second argument with two parameters - a value (which is undefined unless the first argument contains a corresponding numeric property) and an index, which takes values from `0...length-1`. In this example, we have a function that just returns an index + 1, thus giving us `1..length`.

Here's a useful wrapper for the above:

```js
let range = (from, to) => Array.from({length: to - from + 1}, _ => from++);

console.log(range(1, 10))
```

For ES5, the idiom is `Array.apply(null, {length:N})`:

```
r = Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function(_, i) {
    return i + 1
})
```

Comment: What is the ES5 equivalent of this? I tried `Array.prototype.slice.call({length:10})` but it has the same behaviour as `Array(10)`

Comment: @Pavlo: There is none, that's why it was added. :-) But it's trivial to polyfill.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I found it `Array.apply(null, Array(10))`

Comment: @Pavlo: That doesn't do what `Array.from` does. (But it does create an array filled with `undefined`). So to get the `Array.from` you'd add `.map` on the end: `Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function(_, i) { return i + 1; });` Obviously this is slightly less efficient than a real polyfill would be, as it creates and throws away two arrays.

Comment: @Pavlo: added...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes i know, i was more looking for how to create an array of undefined of a given a length, the second argument of `from` is super nice, and probably avoids O(n*2) in order to fill the array

Comment: @Slai doesn't work creating empty x 10 doesn't work with map, probably because it doesn't iterate, when its `[undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]` it works

Comment: yes my bad .. the good old for loop can be used on older browsers or for better performance