# Slow shuffle for large arrays

Tags: javascript, random, shuffle, ecmascript-5, photoshop-script

I'm implementing the Fisher-yates shuffle in a Photoshop script. I want to create an array of `n` unique random elements from a maximum of about 99999. Where `n` is a small value but could be up to to maximum.

With maximum of under a thousand this is fine (runs in milliseconds), but considerably much slower for 10,000 (about 20 seconds).

Is there a better/faster way to do this? Bear in mind that'll it'll need to be in ECMAScript.

```
var maxNumber = 99; 
var numToGenerate = 5; 

var bigShuffle = shuffle(maxNumber);
var randomNumbers = bigShuffle.slice(0, numToGenerate);

alert(randomNumbers);


function shuffle(m)
{

   var temp;
   var rnd;

   // create an empy array
   var arr = new Array();

   for(var i = 0 ; i < m; i++) 
   {
      arr.push(i);
   }

   while (m)
   {
      rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * m-=1);
      // And swap it
      temp = arr[m];
      arr[m] = arr[rnd];
      arr[rnd] = temp;
   }

  return arr; 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962891/fastest-way-to-fill-an-array-with-multiple-value-in-js-can-i-pass-a-some-patter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1)