# Ignore non-standard array keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Say we have this:

```
const v = [1,2,3];
v.foo = 5;

console.log(JSON.stringify(v));
```

we will get:

```
'[1,2,3]'
```

and the 'foo' property on the array will be ignored.
However, if we do:

```
console.log(Object.keys(v));
```

we will get:

```
[ '0', '1', '2', 'foo' ]
```

my question is - how can we get only the standard keys from an array, and ignore any properties that were tacked onto the array?

The only way I know how to do this would be something like:

```
const keys = Object.keys(v).filter(k => Number.isInteger(parseInt(k)));
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you add a key to an array? How do you even end up in such a situation, that you need to fix that?

Comment: @Kresimir it's for a library, I can't control what other people do.

Comment: That's kinda a weird library then.

Comment: I think I might be looking for `Array.prototype.keys()`

Comment: @kinduser the library needs to stringify an object, but handle circular references. JSON.stringify will throw an error upon circular refs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Array.from(v.keys())
```

where [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an iterator over integer indices (not property names!). Notice that in contrast to `Object.keys` it ignores the sparsity of arrays and produces an index even for holes.

I wonder though why you even have to use `Object.keys` on an array. An array has indices only, and you can generate them with a simple `for (let i=0; i<v.length; i++)` loop. Or even with [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/1048572) `Array.from({length: v.length}, (_, i) => i)`.

Comment: yep this is right, I am using `for(let k of keys)` so just `v.keys()` is good.

Answer (score 1):

It is advised to not mess with array keys. V8 does performance evaluation based on array keys and does some pretty nice assumptions which if you modify you will loose all the benefits.

But in case you don't care about performance, than you can create a copy of the array and the engine wont copy custom keys.

`Object.keys([...v])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from`.

```js
const v = [1,2,3];
v.foo = 5;
const keys = Array.from(v);
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: I am looking for the keys of the array, not the values. I think I am looking for `Array.prototype.keys()` => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys