# Create array of decimal values counting down to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, countdown

In JavaScript/jQuery I'm generating value that can vary but is usually something like 0.12 or 0.25.

I want to generate an array that has a set amount of values (around 10 values or so) and include the number above at the start or end of the array. I want these values to decrease to 0 so for example -

var values = [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10, 0.12]

I'm just not quite sure how to acheive this.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the sample input?

Comment: So you're saying you want an array of X values evenly spaced between 0 and Y?

Comment: Seems like a simple division problem with a loop.

Comment: This seems like it could be an XY problem, why do you need this array? What will it be used for?

Comment: I'm sorry the decimal is a claculated probability value for a normal distribution chart so the maths involved to generate that number is complex. All I can say is that I haven;t had a scenario where is goes over 0.3 @Monica Acha

Comment: @cmbuckley Yes exactly.

Comment: Functionally, this problem is the same as [Create a JavaScript array containing 1…N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n).

Answer (score 0):

You could likely solve this with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
function sequence(len, max) {
    return Array.from({length: len}, (v, k) => (k * max / (len - 1)).toFixed(2));
}

console.log(sequence(7, 0.12));
```

Comment: I added `toFixed(2)` in case the floating point issue was a problem for you, but it's quite possible you could remove that entirely.

Comment: Thanks @cmbuckley I'm getting an issue/error with both v and k not being defined. I'm sure I'm being a dummy about it but just need some clarification

Comment: It's quite possible that's a JavaScript version issue.

Comment: If you're running into problems with `Array.from`, it may be better to look at other implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp), or at [Create a JavaScript array containing 1…N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n). underscore.js also has a [`_.range`](https://underscorejs.org/#range) function.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be creating a new array of the predefined length, and then use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to fill the array with the expected values:

```js
const createSeq = (len, val) =>
{
    return new Array(len).fill(0).map((x, i) => val / (len - 1) * i);
}

console.log(createSeq(7, 0.12));
console.log(createSeq(10, 0.25));
```