# For Loop not showing the right result in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a for loop that needs to render `div`s according to some logic:

```
let allRecords;

    if (this.state.allRecords) {
      allRecords = (() => {
        let paramOne = this.state.paramOne;
        let paramTwo = this.state.paramTwo;
        let paramThree = this.state.paramThree;
        let paramFour = this.state.paramFour;
        let paramFive = this.state.paramFive;
        let paramSix = this.state.paramSix;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.length; i++) {
          let res;

          res = (
            <div>
              <div className="event-result-table-container">
                <div className="result-cell">{paramOne[i]}</div>
                <div className="result-cell">
                  <span>{paramTwo[i] ? "Win" : "Lose"}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="result-cell">{paramThree[i]}</div>
                <div className="result-cell">{paramFour[i]}</div>
                <div className="result-cell">{paramFive[i]}</div>
                <div className="result-cell-last">{paramSix[i]}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
          return res;
        }
      })();
    }
```

The six `param` arrays all have a similar structure. For example, I have copied the `paramSix` state array from the Chrome console, and it looks like this:

```
[
  [
    479,
    480,
    481,
    482,
    483,
    484,
    485,
    486,
    487
  ]
]
```

**Expected Result:** I want to see a bunch of `res` blocks rendered (equal to `this.state.length`), each with its correct value taken from the state arrays.

**Observed result:** Only one row of blocks gets rendered, but all the values are there (checked with React DevTools), as if it renders only one block of `div`s, but puts all the values in their cells, instead of putting them in separate blocks.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't return in your for loop. Build an array and return that

Comment: Or even better try using functional `map` functional to build up the new array

Comment: I understand that the map function is the best option here, but I am struggling with applying it in this case. Hence the loop.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp) can give you a clue of how IT could be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you call `return` in your function it stops executing and returns that value. You're calling it within the `for` loop, but it doesn't matter because `for` loops don't work that way, they aren't functions. So the loop doesn't run more than once.

The other issue that you have is that your data, like `paramSix` that you have showed us, is an array with an array of data, so when you reference `paramSix[i]` in the first (and only) execution of the loop, you are referencing an array, not a number. Instead you probably want `paramSix[0][i]`.

Here's a way to rewrite it so that an array of elements is created. Please note that I used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to simplify getting the params from the state, and used `const` since these values shouldn't be changed here:

```
let allRecords = [];

if (this.state.allRecords) {
  const {
    paramOne,
    paramTwo,
    paramThree,
    paramFour,
    paramFive,
    paramSix
  } = this.state;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.length; i++) {
    allRecords.push(
      <div>
        <div className="event-result-table-container">
          <div className="result-cell">{paramOne[0][i]}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">
            <span>{paramTwo[0][i] ? "Win" : "Lose"}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="result-cell">{paramThree[0][i]}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">{paramFour[0][i]}</div>
          <div className="result-cell">{paramFive[0][i]}</div>
          <div className="result-cell-last">{paramSix[0][i]}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.