# How to convert a number into range of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
number = 5
{[...Array(this.props.pages+1)].map((x, i) =>
          <h2 key={i} onClick={()=>this.demoMethod(i+1)} className="tc">{ i+1 }</h2>
)}
//expecting result: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How to convert number to array of range of that number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp)

Answer (score 3):

This is what probably you want.

```
const number = 5;

const result = new Array(number).fill(true).map((e, i) => i+1);

console.log(result); // Consoles  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

In your case you are missing `fill` part.

Use `[...Array(this.props.pages+1)].fill(true).map(...)`

Comment: Alternatively, `Array.from({length: number}, (_, i) => i + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a loop to do what you need. As long as you have the number:

```js
    const number = 5;
    const numberArray = [];
    
    for(let i = 1; i <= number; i++){
        numberArray.push(i);
    }
    console.log(numberArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 Solution:

```
new Array(5).fill(undefined).map((v,i) => i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array.prototype.keys` function to get the iterator of indexes of the generated array. Using the `...` spread operator convert the iterator into an array of numbers till the specified range.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys#Syntax)

> The keys() method returns a new Array Iterator object that contains
>   the keys for each index in the array.

```js
Array.prototype.range = (n) => {
 return [...new Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1, n+1);
}
console.log([].range(5));
```