# create an array of the first n integers in google app script

Tags: arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559488) for an analogous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp) for vanilla JavaScript, I've tried to create an array of integers from 1 to 20 with the following code:

```
var k=Array.from(new Array(20), (x,i) => i + 1);
```

but I get `Syntax error`. Evidently Google App Script does not support ES6.

Is there any modern alternative to `for ... loop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to create an array including the number in each element using Google Apps Script.

  - It's like `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0,,, 20]`

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? Please think of this as just one of several workarounds. In this workaround, I used `Array.apply()`.

#### Sample script 1:

```js
var res = Array.apply(null, Array(20)).map(function(_, i) {return i + 1});
console.log(res); // or for Google Apps Script, Logger.log(res)
```

#### Sample script 2:

In the current stage (2022), the following sample script can be also used.

```js
var res = [...Array(20)].map((_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(res);
```

#### Note:

- For example, when `Array.apply(null, Array(3))` and `[...Array(3)]` are run, an array of `[undefined,undefined,undefined]` is created. In this script, values are put in each element using `map()`. If you want to fill an array by a value, you can also use `Array(3).fill("sample")`.
- Above script can be worked with Google Apps Script.
- If you want to use `Logger.log()`, please replace `console.log(res)` to `Logger.log(res)`.

#### References:

- [Function​.prototype​.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Benchmark: Loop for Array Processing using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski Thank you for your comment of `Your example isn't working for me. I get [undefined,undefined,undefined] regardless of whether I use null, a number or a string. Assuming that close-curly brace is a typo; GAS won't let me insert an open-curly brace anywhere amidst this. function testNewArray () { var result = Array.apply('whatever', Array(3)); console.log (result) }`. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your comment.

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of `Your example isn't working for me.` using your sample value? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `function testNewArray () { var result = Array.apply('whatever', Array(3)); console.log (result) }`, `What is unclear?`, `function testNewArray () { var result = Array.apply(null, Array(3)); console.log (result) } `, I cannot still understand your current issue. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski Thank you for replying. Now, I understood your question. Your are right. `Array.apply(null, Array(20))` returns `[undefined,undefined,,,]`. In the current stage, `fill()` can be used. So, if you want to create `[null,null,,,]`, you can use `Array(20).fill(null)`. And also, in the current stage, I think that `var res = [...Array(20)].map((_, i) => i + 1);` can be also used. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Also, .fill was the method I had forgotten and actually was what I was looking for in the first place!

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

The main issue is that arrays created using `new Array(length)` is sparse and  have  elements  that's never set and most array  methods don't work on it.

#### Solution:

It's possible to create a dense array from sparse array using `apply`. Then, it's easy to get indexes of that array using `Object.keys()`

#### Snippets:

```
//using concat
function test11(){
  Array.prototype.range = function(len){
    return Object.keys(Array.prototype.concat.apply([],new Array(len)))//sparse to dense
  }
  Logger.log([].range(16))
}

//using push
function test12(){
Array.prototype.range = function(len){
  var out = [];
  Array.prototype.push.apply(out,new Array(len))
  return Object.keys(out);
}
Logger.log([].range(15))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. `for`/`while` loop is still best (performant) even on modern browsers. A small function can be used :

```js
function range(n) { var a = []; while(n) a[n - 1] = n--; return a }

console.log( range(5) )
```