# How do I sort an array based on the attribute of corresponding elements of another array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have two arrays. One is :

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
```

and another is,

```
B = [w, x, y, z]
```

Each element in **A** corresponds to the respective element in **B**

```
(i.e. a -> w, b -> x, c -> y, d -> z)
```

Now I want to sort the array **A** in increasing order of an attribute (say value) of the elements of **B**

```
(eg. w.value = 3, x.value = 2, y.value = 1, z.value = 4)
```

Hence, my desired output is:

> [c, b, a, d]

How do I do this using Javascript? Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck at this for a long time.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the indices, sort them with values of `b` and map the values of `a` by taking sorted indices.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ,
    b = [3, 2, 1, 4],
    indices = [...b.keys()].sort((x, y) => b[x] - b[y]),
    result = indices.map(i => a[i]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain a bit on what [...b.keys()] means?

Comment: @Borg1903: It's a trick to generate the array of indices `[0, 1, 2, ..., b.length-1]`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp for more information.

Comment: b.keys() returns the indices for b. b can be thought of as {1:3, 2:2, 3:1, 4:4} - so (s)he sorts b based on it's values. This results in b being {3:1, 2:2, 1:3, 4:4}. Then (s)he maps the b values using a.

Comment: that takes the keys of the array. `keys` is an iterator and to get an array, it needs a spreading into an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone! Got it.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using indexOf and sort

1. Sort array - **a** using sort with **b** array value using the indexOf

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var b = [3, 2, 1, 4]

console.log(a.sort((x,y) => b[a.indexOf(x)] - b[a.indexOf(y)]))
```

Comment: Thanks. And this would have faster execution time than Nina Scholz's answer I guess?