# Range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, range

can I please ask how to make a range in Javascript? For example if I need to print letters "A" to "E" or number 1 to 5. For example in Ruby it is simple double dot like this (1..5).

I tried this code but it gives error.

```
let letter = range("A", "E");
console.log(letter);
```

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp)

Comment: In my opinion this would be the most elegant answer:

    function range (start, end) {
        let out = [];
        for(var i = start.charCodeAt(0); i <= end.charCodeAt(0); i++) {
            out.push(String.fromCharCode(i));        
        }
        return out;
    }
    console.log(range('A', 'D'));

Comment: I favor the generator method, as it can be converted to an array easily `[...range(1,1000)]` but if the range is large, and we only need `for (i of range(1,10000) { ... }`, we don't need to create the big array if not needed to

Answer (score 0):

For numbers you can use ES6 `Array.from()`, [which works in everything these days](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=example#Browser_compatibility) except IE:

Shorter version:

```
Array.from({length: 20}, (x,i) => i);
```

Longer version:

```
Array.from(new Array(20), (x,i) => i)
```

which creates an array from 0 to 19 inclusive. This can be further shortened to one of these forms:

```
Array.from(Array(20).keys())
// or
[...Array(20).keys()]
```

Lower and upper bounds can be specified too, for example:

```
Array.from(new Array(20), (x,i) => i + *lowerBound*)
```

An article describing this in more detail: http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/es6-array-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't include that feature, but you can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#range) which is javascript library which include that feature, and It's only for number.

But you can create your self function which generate range of number and for letters