# Is there a built in way to create an Array of numbers between two numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm given a number. I need to create an array that contains 4 numbers below it, the number itself and then 4 numbers above it.

My naive approach was to create 2 for loops, but I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this using some ES6 syntax.

For example:

generateArray(240) // [236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244 ];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const generateArray = 
    (aroundNumber) => [...Array(9).keys()].map(i => i + aroundNumber - 4);

generateArray(240) // [236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244 ];
```

Explanation:

1. `Array(9)` is creating an array of 9 elements
2. `keys()` methods would return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
3. `map` transforms it to the range you need - it takes the `i` (the number you are transforming to something else) and adds an offset to it (in this case `aroundNumber - 4` because your array is starting 4 elements below the number)

Also, as @Estradiaz mentioned in the comments, you can use `Array.from` method

```
  const generateArray = 
    (aroundNumber) => Array.from({length: 9}, (v, i) => i + aroundNumber - 4);
```

You can read more about the `Array.from()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Thank you! Please could you explain your answer a little bit?

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you. I'm just a little confused how map turns it into the range i need.

Comment: `Array.from({length: top - bottom}, (_, i)=> i + bottom)`

Comment: This would be a great answer... on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i would do it

```js
const generateArray = 
    (aroundNumber, range) => Array(range * 2 + 1).fill(0).map((_, index) => index + aroundNumber - range);

console.log(generateArray(240, 4));


// alternatively generator

function* generateArrayGenerator (value, range) {
  value = value - range;

  for(let _ of Array(range * 2 + 1)) {
    yield value++;
  }
}

console.log([...generateArrayGenerator(240, 4)])
```