# how to get a range number array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to get a range number array and I write this function,

```
public static getNumberRange(from: number, to: number): number[] {

    return Array(to - from + 1).fill().map((v, i) => i + from);
  }
```

but I got a problem, because fill() needs a parameter.

any solution??

Comment: You could just supply any parameter to `fill` - it's going to be ignored in the `.map` anyway. Or you can skip the two passes and do the operations at once with `Array.from({ length: to - from + 1 }, (v, i) => i + from)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static getNumberRange(from: number, to: number): number[] {

    return new Array(to - from + 1).fill('').map((v, i) => i + from);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying thing in JavaScript. If you create an array with X length (e.g. `new Array(5)`) you will get `[empty × 5]` array. Even if this array has 5 length, you can't map it.

And here comes [array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) function. In your case you don't care about the value, so you can just fill with `undefined` values:

```js
Array(to - from + 1).fill(undefined).map((v, i) => i + from)
```

And after filling with `undefined` values, only then you can map it.

---

Also for your case you can find a lot of alternative solutions: [Does JavaScript have a method like “range()” to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp)