# How to get sequential elements from Javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript array:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];
```

I know that I can get each of these elements by index like this:

```
cars[2] // => "BMW"
```

But how can I get **three** sequential elements at once?

```
getThreeCarsByIndex(4) // => ["Fiat", "Saab", "Volvo"]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not clear. please do explain more. is it circularly linked?

Comment: use modular arithmetic - `4 % cars.length`, `(4 + 1) % cars.length`, `(4 + 2) % cars.length`

Comment: cars.slice(1,4)

Comment: youll need to order your array first to get your required values to  the start of the array and then use slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple modular arithmetic-

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];

function getThreeCarsByIndex(ix) {
    return [0, 1, 2].map(offset => cars[(ix + offset) % cars.length]);
}

console.log(getThreeCarsByIndex(4));
```

When `cars.length` is 5, `4 % cars.length` gives you `4`, `5 % cars.length` wraps it back to 0 and so on

Oh and also here's a general version because why not-

```js
function getXElementsFrom(start, x, arr) {
    return [...Array(x).keys()].map(offset => arr[(start + offset) % arr.length]);
}

const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];

console.log(getXElementsFrom(4, 3, cars));
```

`[...Array(x).keys()]` is basically the [equivalent of `range(x)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp) in languages like python.

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo operator to get the desired index without being out of range.

```js
function getThreeCarsByIndex(array, index)
{
  const result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    result.push(array[(index + i) % array.length]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];

console.log(getThreeCarsByIndex(cars, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];

const getThreeCarsByIndex = (index) => cars.slice(index, index + 3).concat(cars.slice(0, (index + 1) % 3))

console.log(getThreeCarsByIndex(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice`. If length is not met (3 here), grab the remaining elements from array begin

```js
const getThreeCarsByIndex = (arr, index) => {
  const res = arr.slice(index, index + 3);
  return res.concat(arr.slice(0, 3 - res.length));
};

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];

console.log(getThreeCarsByIndex(cars, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function and check whether the given count + given index is greater than `length` of the array

```js
const getElementsFromIndex = (arr, ind, n) => {
  if(n + ind > arr.length - 1){
    let elementsFromStart = ind + n - arr.length + 1;
    console.log(elementsFromStart)
    return arr.slice(ind).concat(arr.slice(0, elementsFromStart))
  }
  else return arr.slice(ind, ind + n);
}


const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(getElementsFromIndex(arr, 4, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat", "Saab", "Volvo"];

cars.slice(4, 7); // => ["Fiat", "Saab", "Volvo"]
```

Comment: you've made your own question here

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough just to write

```
cars.sort().slice(1,4);
```

Of course you can create a function that will work for other arrays as well, e.g.

```js
let cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "Fiat"];
    
getSequentionalElements = (arr, firstElement, lastElement) => arr.sort().slice(firstElement, lastElement)

let newArray = getSequentionalElements(cars, 1, 4)

console.log(newArray);
```