# imperative vs declarative JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am doing an exercise about imperative vs declarative. Unfortunately I don't understand the example or I don't get any results. "Uncaught ReferenceError: range is not defined"

```
'use strict'
// imperative
let numbers = range(10)
let evenNumbers = []
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
        evenNumbers.push(numbers[i])
    }
}
console.log(evenNumbers) // => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

and:

```
// declarative
range(10).filter(v => v % 2 === 0) // => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: you can read this article https://dev.to/ycmjason/how-to-create-range-in-javascript-539i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you come from a Python or PHP background, but JavaScript does not have a global `range()`-function. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp) for an alternative.

**Edit:** A simple solution in **this** case would simply be to write:

```js
let numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Sure, it's a bit verbose, but it's also very easy to read, and in a small case like this, it's not problematic.
If the purpose of the exercise was the difference between imperative and declarative programming, `range(2)` vs `[0,1,2]` should not matter.

Comment: This code from above is in my learning script.  Just like that.  I've been learning Javascript for 4 weeks.  But it totally frustrates me when I don't understand things.  Or if you think it makes no sense.

Comment: Could it be that there is a function-definition for `range()` somewhere else? It's not a difficult function to implement, so it could certainly be that a lecturer defined it globally to simplify for the class. As it stands now, no it doesn't make sense, because as you say "`range is not defined`".

Comment: The example actually related them to another. But it was not evident. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! If my answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it as the "right answer" :) Good luck going forward!