# In JavaScript, How do I create an object that has an array of other object?

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript I need an object that has an array of other object

Hi, trying to make a Neural Network on Js.
I need an object that has an array of other object

I create the Neuron object and then I create the Layer object, Layer should have an Neuron Array... How do I write this?

```
//----------------
let Neuron = {
    value: 0    
    Links: []
    Activate: function(){
        //Activacion Sigmoid
        value = (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-value)));
    }
}

let Layer = {
    ??? Neurons: [] new Neuron ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let Layer = {
    Neurons: [...Array(5).keys()].map(() => new {...Neuron})
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is Array(5).keys()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/7195666