# Javascript ReferenceError: range is not defined Error

Tags: javascript

code not working and compiler says "ReferenceError: range is not defined"

code is copied from this famous book:https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#c_EiK2Y8M/Mh
code:

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(action(...range(0, i)));
  }
}
repeat(5, Math.max);
```

I tried let range = new Range(); but it wasn't working

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp

Comment: There is not `Range` in javascript.

Comment: The book makes no claim that `range` exists by itself in JS. And certainly no claim is made that `new Range()` is a thing. The text just illustrates usage of a higher order function without supplying the implementation for it. It even says this: "*The definitions of this vocabulary (the functions sum and range) will still involve loops, counters, and other incidental details. But because they are expressing simpler concepts than the program as a whole, they are easier to get right.*"

Comment: In chapter 4 you were supposed to write a range function... Did you skip chapter 4?

Answer (score -1):

#### Try for 0...n-1, try `Array(n).keys()`

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(action(...Array(i).keys()));
  }
}
repeat(5, Math.max);
```

#### The JS `Range` feature is for text

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const range = new Range();
range.setStartBefore(paragraphs[1]);
range.setEndAfter(paragraphs[2]);

const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.addRange(range);
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two - this will get selected</p>
<p>Three - this will get selected</p>
<p>Four</p>
```