# Method and variable scoping of private and instance variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have tried to figure this out or search for it on google, i can only find how to create objects, not exactly how functions work.  If someone could explain to me how encapsulation works.

```
function myObject() {

    this.variable1 = "tst";

    this.function1 = function() {
        //Now this function works.  A 'this' function to a private function is ok
        _PrivateFunction1();

        //Here is error one, I cannot seem to call methods within the object
        //from.  
        this.function2();
    }

    this.function2 = function() {
        alert("look! function2!");
    }

    function _PrivateFunction1() {
        //This does work though.  I am confused.
        _PrivateFunction2();
    }

    function _PrivateFunction2() {
        alert("look! PrivateFunction1");

        //this does not work.
        alert(this.variable1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call the functions? You can call `_PrivateFunction2` from `_PrivateFunction1` because the live in the same scope (both are inside `myObject`).

Comment: calling this.function2() from inside this.function() likely doesn't work because "this" at that point refers to function2() not to myObject().

Comment: @Michael yeah you have to save a copy of the actual object like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DjPw5/1/) note the `var that = this`

Comment: Once again.. My mind is blow.  Thanks @qwertymk

Comment: Strange. In Chrome, the call to this.function2() works as desired, but the line alert(this.variable1) does not. This seems inconsistent -- unless scope is preserved in anonymous functions (!?). I tested this by placing alert(this.variable1) at the end of the definition for this.function1, and it worked. Huh.

Comment: Yeah.. It seems to be very strange.  I have grown up in the OO Paradigm, so javascript is... well.. its kind of close, i just do not get it yet.

Comment: What browser are you using? I just tried this in IE8, and got the same behavior as I did in Chrome (i.e., I get an alert that says "look! function2!" when I create an object and call its function1()). Unless I'm misreading your post, you do not get such an alert.

Comment: @Seth, @Michael -- It's not strange at all. The call to `this.function2` works because the value of `this` inside `this.function1` is `myObject`. But the value of `this` inside `_PrivateFunction2` is the global object (`window`). So `this.variable1` is looking for a property named `variable1` on the `window` object, which isn't what you intended. How a function is called changes what `this` refers to inside it. Please see my answer below for a much longer explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I can explain this better if we go in reverse order. First, we define some functions:

```
function _PrivateFunction1() {
    //This does work though.  I am confused.
    _PrivateFunction2();
}

function _PrivateFunction2() {
    alert("look! PrivateFunction1");

    //this does not work.
    alert(this.variable1);
}
```

This is pretty normal stuff. The only thing that's weird is that they appear inside another function, but that's perfectly fine. JavaScript has [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures), which means that all variables defined inside a function are defined in a new scope. They do not trample on the global namespace. And functions are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object) in JavaScript, which means they can be used just like other data types. They can be nested, passed to functions, returned from functions, etc.

Then we run into some trouble:

```
    function _PrivateFunction2() {
        alert("look! PrivateFunction1");

        //this does not work.
        alert(this.variable1);
    }
}
```

Functions in JavaScript are always [executed in some *context*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) which is referred to by the `this` keyword. When you call a function directly (i.e. like this: `functionName()`) the context in which that function executes is the global `window` object. So, inside `_PrivateFunction2`, `this.variable1` is equivalent to `window.variable1` which is probably not what you meant.

You probably wanted to refer to the current instance of `myobject` which is what `this` refers to outside of `_PrivateFunction2`. You can preserve access to `this` in an inner scope by storing a reference to it in another variable:

```
var _this = this;

function _PrivateFunction2() {
    alert("look! PrivateFunction1");

    //this does not work.
    alert(_this.variable1);
}
```

There's something subtle here you should notice. `_PrivateFunction2` has access to the variables defined in its [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), which is why it can access `_this`. This will be important later.

Next up:

```
    function _PrivateFunction1() {
        //This does work though.  I am confused.
        _PrivateFunction2();
    }
```

This should be the most normal-looking section to you, I would think. There's nothing strange going on here. Just one regular function calling another one. Don't be confused by the fact that these are nested inside `myObject`. That changes the scope they're in, but not much else.

Next we define some instance variables and methods:

```
this.variable1 = "tst";

this.function1 = function() {
    //Now this function works.  A 'this' function to a private function is ok
    _PrivateFunction1();

    //Here is error one, I cannot seem to call methods within the object
    //from.  
    this.function2();
}

this.function2 = function() {
    alert("look! function2!");
}
```

Here `this` really does refer to `myObject`, assuming -- and it's an important assumption -- that `myObject` was called with the `new` operator, like this:

```
var obj = new myObject();
```

If it had been called like this:

```
var obj = myObject();
```

Then `this` would refer to the `window` object, just like it did for the functions we saw earlier. The key takeaway is that the value of `this` is not fixed. It's determined by the way in which the function is called. There are even ways to [set it to an arbitrary object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) explicitly.

The value of `this` inside `this.function1` will also be the current instance of `myObject`, because it will most likely be used like this:

```
var obj = new myObject();
obj.function1();
```

Writing `object.method()` sets `this` to `object` inside `method`.

So how is `this.function1` able to call `_PrivateFunction1()`? Just as we saw earlier when saving the value of `this` for use inside a nested function, `_PrivateFunction1()` is just another object defined in `this.function1`'s lexical scope, so it is available for its use, just as `_this` was earlier.

And it's [because of closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) that these private variables are still alive long after `myObject` has returned.

Footnote: Because failing to use `new` when instantiating objects [breaks things so spectacularly without warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful), it's considered good practice to capitalize the names of functions you intend to be used as a constructor. So `myObject` should really be `MyObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the more verbose answer.  I have a degree in CS so it helps.  Since i always studied Java/C#, 'this' keyword, in the light of using inside of an object, really confused me with javascript.  With this i should be better at javascript! thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a copy of the actual object like **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DjPw5/2/)** note the `var that = this`

Tested in chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

for encapsulation I would prefer module pattern like

```
var someMethod = function(){



     var i, 
         length,

     // public method
     public = function(num1, num2){
            return num1+num2;
     },

    //private method
     _private = function(){};

    //exposing the public method

     return{
       public:public
     }

};

var callPublic = someMethod();
callPublic.public(20, 30);// call the public method and return 50
```

now , if you try to call that private method like

```
callPublic._private();//it will return not a function since its not been exposed
```

There are lot of other pattern to encapsulate your methods but module pattern is most common. Hope ot will help you how to encapsulate data in javascript.