# can someone tell me how/why this works in ff and ie

Tags: javascript

```
--script--
function myalert(name){
  var obj=this;
  obj.run=run;
  function run(){
    alert(name);
  }    
  div=document.createElement('div');
  div=document.body.append(div);
  txt=document.createTextNode('alert');
  div.appendChild(txt);
  //**
  div.onclick=function(){ obj.run(); }
  //**
}
--html--
<div onclick="myalert('mee');">matt</div>
```

the thing i find strange, is the obj.run() is called outside the function, from a dom element, and the function parameter is also preserved

also are there any pitfalls to this method?

Comment: `appendChild` instead of `append`

Comment: And the `div` name is bleeding into the global namespace... (it's not declared as a local variable)

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Closure**.

There is [a lot to read](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=14&gs_id=b&xhr=t&q=javascript%20closure&qe=amF2YXNjcmlwdCBjbG8&qesig=ZMjY3aAyxYcYhCm2eGa8Qg&pkc=AFgZ2tmeLBNOcQs6KSVsQTGXamg2DZWjF5SDPaepRzoxqTlJWhNx_JMxbxqlE7-HwegoWyZ4ADZuziC8f9sEyczOy8ELjjVm_Q&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=javascript%20clo&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f10181c958c90d45&biw=1366&bih=643&ion=1) on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an understanding of "lexical scope".  Here's one explanation: [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)