# call function using if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to call a function within an if statement.

For example:

```
var photo = "yes";

if (photo=="yes") {

    capturePhoto();

}

else {
  //do nothing
};
```

This does nothing though. The function is clearly defined above this if statement.

Edit: Wow, downboated to hell! capturePhoto(); was just an example function that didn't really need any more explanation in this scenario?

Comment: Let's see the function definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "does nothing"? Does the function not get called or does it not do what you're expecting it to? What is the function -supposed- to do (posting the code would be useful!) that it doesn't?

Comment: And what does `capturePhoto()` do? Unless your JS/browser install is totally hosed, or either of those `yes` strings are ninjas pretending to be yesses, there's no way that this code could NOT call capturePhoto.

Comment: A side note: you might want to use `true`/`false` boolean constants rather than `"yes"`/`"no"` strings. You could then format your `if` as `if (photo) capturePhoto();`.

Comment: Why do people ask for help with their code, but then don't provide the code?

Comment: What *Xion* said. Using `true` and `false` it making the code more readable and the execution is faster. If you are retrieving in your real code `"yes"/"no"` from user then just convert it to boolean `var photo = input === "yes";`.

Comment: I can't update RightSaidFred's comment enough. *POST YOUR DAMN CODE PEOPLE!*

Comment: @RightSaidFred - It's clearly defined. Don't worry about it.

Comment: LordSnoutimus: You've provided nothing of use in your question. If you really don't know if the `if` test should work, then you need to read a very basic programming tutorial. If you're having an issue in your actual code, then **you need to provide the code that is giving you the issue**. If you genuinely believe that the problem is with the `if`, and not your other code, then you need to learn some basic troubleshooting skills because they would lead you to the conclusion that the `if` will work properly. This question deserves far more downvotes than it has received.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That should work. Maybe `capturePhoto()` has a bug?
Insert an `alert()` or `console.log()`:

```js
var photo = "yes";
if (photo == "yes") {
 alert("Thank you StackOverflow, you're a very big gift for all programmers!");
 capturePhoto();
} else {
  alert("StackOverflow.com must help me!");
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be written '`It works!`' it should be written - '`thank you  StackOverflow!`' !

Comment: @Aleks Why should the code thank StackOverflow if we haven't done anything except saying that `capturePhoto()` could have a bug? *BTW this is more than a year old ;)*

Comment: Because javascript doesn't report errors like we would want :) And even it is old more then a year, mentioning a word - `bug` stopped me for a second, and I figured a solution for my similar javascript problem not running a function. Even it is a year old I had to say it helped me +1 ;)

Comment: @Aleks I'm glad that I could point you in the right direction :) Thank you, thank StackOverflow (see edit)! ;)

Comment: hehe :D it is absolutely true!! ;) thanks, have a happy programming ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing any problems here. I used this code and the function call worked. I kept your code and just added a function called capturePhoto().

Are you sure that the code you're using to call the function is firing?

```
var photo = "yes"; 
if (photo=="yes") 
{ 
    capturePhoto(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    //do nothing 
};
function capturePhoto() 
{ 
    alert("Pop up Message"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed something, a quotation, a semicolon or something like that. I would recommend you to use a debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or even Google Chrome's Web Developer Tool. You will know what's wrong with your code and where it is wrong.

You may take a look at this live code that your code above works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHbqK/

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me (except you don't need the `;` at the end of the last line).  Check your error log; perhaps the browser thinks `capturePhoto` is not defined [for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope).  You can also add `alert` statements to make sure the code is actually running:

```
var photo = "yes";

alert('Entering if statement');

if (photo=="yes") {
    alert('then');
    capturePhoto();
} else {
    alert('else');
    //do nothing
}
```

When you encounter a situation where it seems like a fundamental language feature is not working, get some more information about what is going on.  It is almost never the platform's fault.  It is occasionally a misunderstanding of how the feature works (e.g. why does `parseInt('031') == 25` ?).  It is usually a violation of an assumption you're making about the code that isn't holding up because of a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using `true` and `false` instead of strings that could be manipulated depending on input.

If I had to correct the following code, then I should've done it like this;

```js
var photo = true; // Will capture picture.
if (photo) { // 'true' is a truthy value.
    capturePhoto();
} else {
  // Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted does work.

I copied it and tested it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/vraPQ/

The only thing wrong with it that I can see is a semicolon after the closing bracket, but that is only a style problem. It will form an extra empty statement, but that doesn't cause any problems.