# Why can deep nested function access top level vars?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been doing some javascript reading, and I've gathered that a closure has access only to the closure "wrapping" it, or, you might say it's immediate parent. Now I've been playing a bit, and I see in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPQ4s/) that even deep nested functions have access to to vars defined way up.

Can anyone please explain that? Or explain what have I got completely wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/tPQ4s/

```
function runNums() {
    this.topVar = 'blah';
    return function(){
        (function() {                    
            (function() {
                console.log(topVar);
            })();
        })();
    }
}

var someFunc = runNums();
someFunc();
```

Comment: Yes, closure "closes around" the variables that it can see at all parent levels.

Comment: An enclosed function can see all the way up??

Comment: If you actually read that from somewhere, you might wanna stop reading materials that have blatant misinformation :P Of course it can access all parent levels.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope.

Comment: I would expect it to work this way just because that's also how scope works in general for nested functions/procedures in quite a wide variety of languages. If it didn't work this way also for closures it would be confusing. Or, to answer your question with two words: why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the chain runs further up to the top context.
In the example, that would be:

```
window < runNums < anonymous < anonymous < anonymous
```

Variables living in any of these will be available in the last anonymous function. In runNums, only variables living in runNums or window will be available. In the first anonymous function, only its variables and those living in runNums or window will be available, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Without going too deep into the details, a `closure` technically describes a `array like variable` within the such called *Activation Object* that is handled from the javascript engine. An ActivationObject contains *Variables declared by `var`*, *function declarations* and *formal parameters*.

That means, anytime a new function (-context) is invoked, internally a new Activation Object is created. That object is part of the new `Execution Context`, a typicall EC looks like:

- this context variable
- Activation Object
- [[Scope]]

The interesting part here is `[[Scope]]`. That variable contains **all** Activation Objects of **all** parent context and is filled when the EC is called. So now, when a function wants to access a variable, the name resolution process first looks into its own Activation Object, if nothing is found the search continues in the "Scope chain", which is just an *Indexed search* through our [[Scope]] variable (which again, is an array of parent contexts). Thats why we also speak a lot about "lexical scope" in ECMA-/Javascript.

<sup>Note: The above behavior is not described entirely, that would need several pages of text. Also it describes the ECMAscript3 262 specification. Things work a little different in ES5, but its still around the same thing</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**this** is nothing but the Window object here.

Here **runNums** is a global function and **runNums()** is equal to **window.runNums()**. So **this** is **window** and **this.topVar** is **window.topVar**. Obviously it will be accessible from anywhere.

Try this and see the difference

```
var someFunc = new runNums();
someFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

The deep nested functions have not been executed. You did not return them for executing.