# what is the difference between these two Scheme functions?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

1. ```
   (define self-add
   (let ((x 0))
     (lambda ()
       (set! x (+ x 1))
       x)))
   ```

> (self-add) => 1
>
> (self-add) => 2
>
> (self-add) => 3
>
> (self-add) => 4

  2.

```
 (define self-add1
    (lambda ()
      (let ((x 0))
        (set! x (+ x 1))
        x)))
```

> (self-add1) => 1
>
> (self-add1) => 1
>
> (self-add1) => 1

Please tell me how to understand the difference between the above two functions?
Thanks a lot in advance!
Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried *using* those functions to see what they do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first function defines a local variable `x` with an initial value of `0` and *afterwards* binds a lambda special form to the name `self-add` - so `x` is "enclosed" by the lambda (that's why we say that the lambda from behaves as a [**closure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))) and will be the *same* for all invocations of `self-add` (you could say that `x` is "remembered" by `self-add`), and each time it gets called the value of `x` will be incremented by one.

The second function binds the lambda to the procedure and *afterwards* defines a local variable `x` inside the lambda - here `x` is redefined each time `self-add1` gets called, and will be *different* for all invocations: so `x` is never "remembered" by `self-add1` and is created anew every time the procedure gets called, initialized with `0` and then incremented, always returning the value `1`.

Comment: @abelard20008 My pleasure! welcome to Stack Overflow, please remember to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Comment: can I think that x in second function is a local variable? thanks

Comment: @abelard20008 absolutely, that's what it is: a variable local to each invocation of the function, whereas in the first function `x` is shared by all invocations of the function

Answer (score 1):

The first function is *closure*. You create `x` variable in the lexical scope of the function and the variable holds its value between calls.

Additional information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)
- [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)

Comment: where to get the knowledge about Scheme's closure, I didn't find anything about in book "The Scheme programming language 4th edition",Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First function is a closure, while second function simply returns the same function every time, which makes x = 0 and then adds one and returns the result.

Comment: where to get the knowledge about Scheme's closure, I didn't find anything about in book "The Scheme programming language 4th edition",Thanks !

Comment: I recommend that you read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). It's free and a very good Computer Science book that happens to be using Scheme. It covers usage of closures as well. Good luck.