# ng-model from angular-payments is not working

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments, angularjs-model

I am trying to add [angular-payments](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) in order to integrate stripe.com payment processing to my AngularJS web app.

I duplicated the code from https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments/blob/master/lib/angular-payments.js into my angular-payments.js file and the code from https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments/blob/master/example/index.html into localhost:8888/stripe.html and got it to work.

However, when I try to integrate this code to my AngularJS web app, the ng-model is not working.

Here is how I integrated the code.  I have a single page web app with app.js, which has the following code:

```
angular.module('io.config', []).value('io.config', {
'password': 'json/config.password.json',
    ....
    ....
});
...
...
angular.module('app.modules', ['app.config']);
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies', 'io', 'ui', 'bs', '$strap',
'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.factories', 'app.filters', 'app.modules', 'app.config']);
```

So, I added 'angularPayments' to:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies', 'io', 'ui', 'bs', '$strap',
'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.factories', 'app.filters', 'app.modules', 'app.config', 'angularPayments']);
```

I also have an app.route.js file, which has the following code:

```
angular.module('app')
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    var _view_ = 'view/', _app_ = 'app/';
    $routeProvider
    .when('/user/invite',           {templateUrl:_view_+'app/invite.html'})
```

I added the following to app.route.js:

```
    .when('/user/buy',              {templateUrl:_view_+'app/buy.html'})
```

I duplicated the code from localhost:8888/stripe.html into app/buy.html, which maps to localhost:8888/#/user/buy

The exception is that I took the following lines out of buy.html and put them into index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/angular-payments.js"></script>
```

My index.html has this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
...
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<body class="ng-cloak" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
...
<div data-ng-view></div>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-io/src/scripts/ie.js"></script>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-complete/angular.js"></script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="scripts/modules/angular-payments.js"></script>
...
```

Both stripe.html and buy.html has the following code:

```
       <form stripe-form="handleStripe">

          <div class="span3">
            <label for="">Card number</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" />
          </div>

          <div class="span1">
            <label for="">Expiry</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" />
          </div>

          <div class="span3">
            <label for="">Name on card </label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
          </div>

          <div class="span1">
            <label for="">CVC</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" />
          </div>

          <div class="span4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Submit</button>
          </div>
          number:{{number}}, expiry:{{expiry}}, cvc:{{cvc}}
        </form>
```

However, the following code works in stripe.html but not in buy.html, as no values are coming back from the ng-model:

```
          number:{{number}}, expiry:{{expiry}}, cvc:{{cvc}}
```

Hence, when I submit this form, Stripe returns an error with status = 402 because nothing is passed to Stripe.

I've tried changing ng-model to data-ng-model, but to no avail.  I've tried putting the following code into a separate file: scripts/controllers/payment.js:

```
function PaymentCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    if(response.error) {
      // there was an error. Fix it.
    } else {
      // got stripe token, now charge it or smt
      token = response.id
    }
  }
}
```

and adding the following to app.route.js:

```
.when('/user/buy',  {templateUrl:_view_+'app/buy.html', controller:PaymentCtrl})
```

and changing the following in buy.html:

```
data-ng-controller="MainController"
```

to:

```
data-ng-controller="PaymentCtrl"
```

but still to no avail.

Can anyone tell me how to get the ng-model variables to work in buy.html?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tip from [Ng-model does not update controller value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value) and I solved the problem with a convoluted solution.

I added the following code to MainController in buy.html:

```
    $scope.payment = {};

    $scope.copyvariables = function() {
        $scope.number = $scope.payment.number;
        $scope.expiry = $scope.payment.expiry;
        $scope.cvc = $scope.payment.cvc;
    }
```

Then I added "payment." to the ng-model variables, like such:

```
          <div class="span7">
            <label for="">Card number</label>
            <input id="number" name="number" type="text" class="input-block-level" data-ng-model="payment.number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" required />
          </div>

          <div class="span4" style="border: 1px solid red">
            <label for="">Expiry</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" data-ng-model="payment.expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" required />
          </div>

          <div class="span8">
            <label for="">Name on card </label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="input-block-level" required />
          </div>

          <div class="span3">
            <label for="">CVC</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" data-ng-model="payment.cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" required />
          </div>
```

Now the following code works and the values are being passed to Stripe:

```
number:{{number}}, expiry:{{expiry}}, cvc:{{cvc}}
```

I still don't know why I need this for buy.html but stripe.html works without this extra code.