# AngularJS ng-model not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this index.html which has a navbar in the  which is seen on all pages of my single page application. The navbars container div is using the `ng-controller="LoginCtrl"` value, so I will also include that controller from my angular application (app.js)

For some reason, the variables `username` and `password` which are bound via `ng-model` are showing as undefined when `doLogin()` is called via `ng-click` directive? That is after I type values into the text boxes that are bound to my controllers variables.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <base href="/">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.9/ngStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TriviaAttack!</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <form ng-if="!loggedIn" id="loginForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="doLogin()">Sign In</button>
                        </div>                  
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="./app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
...
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($rootScope, $location, AuthService, AuthToken) {

    $rootScope.doLogin = function() {
        console.log($rootScope.username);
        console.log($rootScope.password);
    }

});
...
```

Comment: Use `$scope` rather than `$rootScope`. We should have to make our `$rootScope` as thinner as possible for an app.

Comment: Hi, $scope does not work either, both say undefined.

Comment: Share more code or create a fiddle. I can not see your module declaration

Comment: Here is my module declaration

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ng-model does not update controller value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question after some frustration. Adding username and password arguments to my `doLogin()` function, then using the directive `ng-click="doLogin(user.name, user.pass)"` works as I wanted.  No clue why it wasn't working the way I was trying, but oh well.

Comment: **Very frustrating...** I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out why exactly the same issue is happening to me while I was developing a new module for my main app.
Just tried doing what you suggested and it works..

Inside my app, I have other functions which manipulate models without specifying them as arguments and work flawless.

_Can you mark your answer as accepted or the main one? I think it could help others in our exact situation_

Comment: @DincăAlexandru Hey I marked it, but I was somehow able to get it to work without having to supply my variables as arguments to doLogin().  But, this also did solve my original issue for whatever reason.

Comment: Hey @David, I guess you can't explain that *somehow*?  I'm still curious why I wasted those hours on something as trivial as this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768720/1885735 String is a primitive. When Angular assigns the value it changes the pointer to the value. So when the controller looks at the old value it has the old pointer to the value.

Answer (score 2):

An `inputModel` primitive property will be created on that `ng-controller`'s scope when you type into the text field. input model is generated in the current scope, not the `rootScope`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
        console.log($scope.username);
        console.log($scope.password);
    }
});
```

Check it out on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/40UaPR6QIGgGOFIrpBeG?p=preview)

Comment: injecting $scope into LoginCtrl was what I was originally trying to do, but it wasn't working so I just tried $rootScope

Comment: I have updated my code back to using $scope as you are showing, and it is not working.

Comment: Nope, just sharing $scope.username and $scope.password are undefined in the console.log output.  Even though they are bound to $scope variable via ng-model="username" on a textbox in index.html

Comment: @DavidStampher please check now

Comment: Check the answer I posted below, I added parameters to doLogin(user, pass), and called doLogin in my ng-click button like this doLogin(user.name, user.pass) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use model rather than using primitive types.

You should use `$rootScope.user.name` (`ng-model` will be `user.name`) rather than using `$rootScope.username` and `$rootScope.user.password`(`ng-model` will be `user.password`) instead of `$rootScope.password`

This problem actually happens for javascript's prototypical model. And if you want to know it's applicability in angularjs, you can go through this [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). This will definitely help :)

Edit: As you are running into problem making that code work, I've made a working copy of your code. Please have a look at it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <base href="/">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.9/ngStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TriviaAttack!</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <form ng-if="!loggedIn" id="loginForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="doLogin()">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

        $scope.user = { name: "", password: "" };
        $scope.doLogin = function () {
            console.log($scope.user.name);
            console.log($scope.user.password);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I changed ng-model in index.html to ng-model="user.name" and in my LoginCtrl's doLogin function to this: console.log($rootScope.user.name); and it says cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

Comment: You need to initialize the object first. May be with an empty object. like
$rootScope.user ={name:"",password:""};

Comment: I have just done this, and it made the exception I mentioned go away, but the variables are not being updated when I type text into the input boxes, according to console.log which is called in doLogin

Comment: So it is showing $rootScope.user.name is an empty string, as it was initialized too, even though it should have been updated by ng-model

Comment: I've edited my answer for your convenience. Please have a look

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code and console.log shows that $scope.user.name and $scope.user.password are both empty strings when doLogin is called, even though I am entering text into the textboxes that are bound via ng-model

Answer (score 1):

use `$scope` instead of `$rootScope` for getting the `ng-model` in controller.

Comment: I have injected $scope into LoginCtrl, created an empty JSON object called user with properties name and pass, attached that to $scope, and updated my ng-models to user.name and user.pass, and console.log is showing user.name and user.pass as empty strings, even though they should have had their values updated due to ng-model?

Comment: app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
        console.log($scope.username);
        console.log($scope.password);
    }
});