# ng-model undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

the ng-model I have in html **has** a dot in it. let's take a look

**step1.html file**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
    <select id="plateId" ng-model="selectedPlate.plate" ng-options="plate.id as (plate.wafer_id + ' - ' + plate.serial_number) for plate in plates" />
    <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It's simply a form-wizard using ui-router.

This is my other html file. In step 3 the user pushes the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-next" ng-click="storePlatesInspection()">
    Submit
    <i class="ace-icon fa  icon-on-right"></i>
</button>
```

And my **controller**  look like this.

```
angular.module('sxroApp')
    .controller('plateInspectionCtrl', function ($scope, PlatesInspectionFactory, PlatesFactory, PlateQualityFactory, EquipmentStatusCodesFactory, PlateContainersFactory, $location) {
    // object to hold all the data for plate inspection
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.selectedPlate = {};

    $scope.inspectionData = {

        equipment_status_codes_id: 1,
        plate_container_id: 1,
        plate_container_slot: 34,
        plate_quality_id: 1

    }

    PlatesFactory.query(function (plates) {
        $scope.plates = plates;

    });

    /*    $scope.getSelectedPlate = function(plate)
            {
              $scope.data.push({

                  plate_id : plate.id
             });*/

    //  console.log($scope.selectedPlate.id)
    //alert(item.wafer_id)
    //PlatesInspectionFactory.update( {id : $scope.plateid[0].plate_id}, $scope.inspectionData)

    PlateQualityFactory.query(function (platequality) {
        $scope.platequality = platequality;

    })

    PlateContainersFactory.query(function (plateContainers) {
        $scope.plateContainers = plateContainers;

    });

    EquipmentStatusCodesFactory.query(function (statuscodes) {
        $scope.statuscodes = statuscodes;
    });

    $scope.storePlatesInspection = function () {

        alert($scope.selectedPlate.plate.id); // not working
        alert($scope.selectedPlate.plate.$id); // not working

    }
});
```

I also tried

```
alert($scope.selectedPlate.plate); // undefined is the result.
```

I basically followed what this gentleman was saying

[Ng-model does not update controller value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value/22768720#22768720)

Would someone show me what I am doing wrong?

here is an image of the form [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnVmG.png)

I am trying to use the model to get the selection the user does during the wizard process.

**update #1**: I have updated the code above.

Comment: Is this inside a repeater? If you select something does it work? What is `$scope.plates`?

Comment: Where is `storePlatesInspection ()` called? Also seems to be conflict between `.$id` and `.id`. Log `$scope.selectedPlate` to console and inspect it

Comment: Could you post your code please? Tell us what contains $scope.plates also please :) Thanks, Diane

Comment: @ tymeJV It does work if I select something, but just not sending id back to controller.  And what do you exactly mean by $scope.plates? Which line?

Comment: Well why are you using `.$id` instead of `id`?

Comment: @DianeDuquesne I have updated the code with more details and an image of the process I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @tymeJV I have tried both .id &  .$id but non worked.

Comment: Can we see the data structure of `$scope.plates` - is there even an `id` property/

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @tymeJV Its simple data coming from API. Of course it has id property.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<select id="plateId" 
        ng-model="selectedPlate.plate" 
        ng-options="plate for plate in plates"/>
     <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

See different way of [ddl bindings](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1196/angularjs-dropdown-select-value-text-multiple-values-with-demo)

Comment: I have tried this countless times. And I appears not to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `alert($scope.selectedPlate.plate);` is not working, but you are passing the value of your ID property to `$scope.selectedPlate.plate`, so it won't hold a "plate object" with an ID property in it, it's just a number (or whatever ID is).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ui-router before but it may be that you have specified a directive or a routing path along with the controllerAs property. 
If controllerAs is specified then the variables stored on $scope in the controller would be accessed via the controllerAs value in the view html.

For example, if the directive was declared as such:

```
angular.module('sxroApp')
    .directive('plateInspectionDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'plateInspection.html',
            controller: plateInspectionCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'plateInspection',
            scope: {
            }
        };
    });
```

Then the view would require the controller name plateInspection to access the variables on it's scope.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
<select id="plateId" ng-model="plateInspection.selectedPlate.plate" ng-options="plate.id as (plate.wafer_id + ' - ' + plate.serial_number) for plate in plateInspection.plates" />
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```