# Ionic/AngularJS: local data is showing up blank when form is submited

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to save the data from a form, which is in a modal, to local storage. But, for some reason, the data is coming up blank.

For example, when I get the data, it returns this:

**, , , , ,**

instead of this:

**Name, Email, Year, Major, Phone#**

So, it seems like it is saving a blank entry. I'm very new to AngularJS so I can't figure out how to fix it. If anyone could help me out that would be amazing!

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppController',['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', '$ionicModal', function ($scope, getLocalStorage, $ionicModal) {
    $scope.todos = getLocalStorage.getTodos();

    $scope.clearSelected = function () {
        $scope.todos = $scope.todos.filter(function (item) {
            return !item.selected;
        });
        getLocalStorage.updateTodos($scope.todos);

    };

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      }, {
        animation: 'slide-in-up',
        focusFirstInput: true
      });
}])

.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', function ($scope, getLocalStorage) {

  $scope.todos = getLocalStorage.getTodos();

  $scope.addTodo = function () {
      $scope.todos.push(
        {'name': $scope.name,
         'email': $scope.email,
         'year': $scope.year,
         'major': $scope.major,
         'phone': $scope.phone,
         'selected': false});
      $scope.modal.hide();
      getLocalStorage.updateTodos($scope.todos);
  };
}])

.controller('InfoCtrl', ['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', function ($scope, getLocalStorage) {
    $scope.todos = getLocalStorage.getTodos();
}
]);
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

var storageService = angular.module('storageService', []);

storageService.factory('getLocalStorage', function () {

    var todoList = {};

    return {
            list: todoList,

        updateTodos: function (todosArr) {
            if (window.localStorage && todosArr) {
                localStorage.setItem("todos", angular.toJson(todosArr));
            }
            //update the cached version
            todoList = todosArr;
        },

        getTodos: function () {
            todoList = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem("todos") );
            return todoList ? todoList : [];
        }
    };

})
```

**html**

```
<ion-view view-title="TechProf">
  <ion-content>
  <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="modal.show()">OPen Modal</button>

      <ion-list>
          <h3>List</h3>
        <ul class="list">
           <li ng-repeat="s in todos" class="item">
               <input ng-model="s.selected" type="checkbox" />
               <span ng-class="{'selected': todo.selected}">{{ s.name }}, {{ s.email }}, {{ s.year }},{{ s.major }}, {{ s.phone }}</span>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="clearSelected()">Delete Selected</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="modal" ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
          <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
            <h1 class="title">New Contact</h1>
            <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
          </header>
          <ion-content has-header="true">
          <form name="frm" ng-submit="addTodo()">
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">Year</div>
            <select ng-model="year" required>
              <option selected>Freshman</option>
              <option >Sophmore</option>
              <option>Junior</option>
              <option>Senior</option>
            </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Major" ng-model="major" required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="number" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="phone" ng-minlength="10" required>
            </label>
            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-disabled="frm.$invaild">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          </ion-content>
        </div>
      </script>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/thV2Op?p=preview)

### ngModel

One of the keys to getting this is move all of the form inputs `ng-model` point to an object.property like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768720/5357459) suggests.

Basically that means you need to do something like this for your **HTML** inputs:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info.name">
```

And put this in your **controller**:

```
$scope.info = {};
```

Because of the ngModel you'll need to change the `$scope.addTodo` function. While you're at it you can also reset the form data on submit by adding `$scope.info = {};`.

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push($scope.info);
    $scope.modal.hide();
    getLocalStorage.updateTodos($scope.todos);
    $scope.info = {};
};
```

You can also move it from `ModalCtrl` to your `AppController` because you won't need the `ModalCtrl` anymore.

### Modal Scope

Add `scope: $scope` to your modal so it uses the scope from your `AppController`.

Like this:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
}, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    focusFirstInput: true
});
```

### Remove

Remove the `ModalCtrl` controller and the `ng-controller="ModalCtrl"` from your HTML.

In **services.js** remove this (it's unnecessary):

```
var storageService = angular.module('storageService', []);

storageService
```

### Change

In your `getLocalStorage` factory, change this `var todoList = {}` to this `var todoList = []` because you want an array of objects so you need to start with an array.

In your modal's HTML change `<ion-content has-header="true">` to `<ion-content class="has-header">` as [suggested by Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-content-has-header-being-ignored/1993/2?u=adriancarriger).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for days. One more question: how would I add an edit function? I have some idea but I'm not sure how to actually do it in code.

Comment: Try [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JO4g3N?p=preview). I put a few comments in the controller to show what was changed. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!