# Angular ng-model is being set to undefined on edit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm creating a modal dialog and trying to read the fields back when the dialog is closed, but when the input is edited, the ng-model for the input field is being set to undefined.  With the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5IkjzoN6IjewGl4RDJq), if you click the dialog button and then press Ok without modifying the text field, it will display "blah".  But if you modify the text input at all, then nothing will be displayed.

The dialog template is:

```html
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="simpleModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Simple Modal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailInput">Email</label>
        <input id="emailInput" type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>
    </div>
  </script>
```

And the controller for the modal dialog:

```js
app.controller('SimpleModalController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $log) {

  $scope.user = {
    email: "blah"
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $log.debug('simpleModal ok called ' + $scope.user.email);
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.user.email);
  };

});
```

I've seen reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768720/552936, but I've changed my code to reflect this and it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: type is email - if you type a valid email it works. If it is not a valid email it will be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared input `type="email"` in your input field in modal

```
<input id="emailInput" type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
```

It'll pass value if data according to email . like `a@b.com`

You can check  if data has valid email

HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="email" name="myEmail" model="myEmail" />
  <span>Valid Email {{myForm.myInput.$valid}}
</form>
```

<kbd>**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/mREsyJ0tBJIbAzGEzYYT?p=preview)**</kbd>

If you wanna pass any string then you have to make it `type="text"`.

Comment: Dammit I've spent 2 days trying to debug why this was happening only to find that the issue was sloppy copy paste on input fields. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's being set to undefined is because you have the input for the email address as type=email. If you put anything but a valid email address in that field user.email will be set to undefined.

I just ran your plunker and put in a valid email address and can see it's has been set correctly. This is an instance where you should be validating that it's a well formed email address before allowing submission.