# Angular $scope variables not updating in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My variables are not updating in the controller and I have no idea why.

In the view I have this code

```
<div ng-if="state_1">
    <input ng-model='amount'> {{amount}} <!-- this binds perfectly -->
    <button ng-click='submitForm()'>Submit</button>
</div>
<div ng-if="state_2">
    <input ng-model='txcode'> {{txcode}} <!-- this binds perfectly -->
    <button ng-click='submitCode()'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
angular.module('myapp')
   .controller('RecCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $http) {
      $scope.submitForm = function(){
         console.log($scope.amount);    //returns undefined 
      }
   })
```

[I followed this answer and worked around it by passing the `amount` into `submitForm()` from the view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value) But now I need to use a value from `$rootScope`  but nothing shows. Nothing works in this controller except for that `$scope.submitForm()`. Every other controller is working fine.

If it will help, there are 2 states using the same controller and template like so:

```
//initiate payment tx 
    .state('rec', {
      url: '/receive',
      templateUrl: 'views/rec.html',
      controller: 'RecCtrl'
    })

    //claim payment tx 
    .state('claim', {
      url: '/claim',
      templateUrl: 'views/rec.html',
      controller: 'RecCtrl'
    })
```

I use the `$state.current.name` to separate the functions. But I have tried deleting the other one, it still didn't work. Other controllers are working fine.

Comment: Shouldn't this `$scope.submitForm(){}` be `$scope.submitForm = function(){}`.

Comment: @RaviTeja It was a typo. I have updated it, thank you.

Comment: Do you have `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-include` or other directives in your HTML file? I you can show your complete html it will help.

Comment: Yeah, I have ng-if. That is how I separate the 2 states. I've update the code to show the rest of the html @RaviTeja

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ng-if` creates a new scope. So, you cannot directly use primitive values, use reference values.

If you use primitive values they will be local to `ng-if` scope. So, you cannot access them from your controller.

If you use reference value, `ng-model` checks if the value exists in `ng-if` scope, if it does not then it looks the value in parent scope which is `RecCtrl` scope in this case.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) will help you to understand why you should use reference  values.

```
angular.module('myapp')
   .controller('RecCtrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $http) {
      // use a reference value
      $scope.details={};
      $scope.submitForm = function(){
         console.log($scope.details.amount);   
      }
   })
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model='details.amount'> {{details.amount}} 
<button ng-click='submitForm()'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I removed the ng-if completely. Too much headache!