# Different Angular scope variabes behaviour

Tags: html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model="test1.param">
<input ng-model="test2">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.test1 = { param: null };
$scope.test2 = null;
```

After entering some text in both inputs:

- `$scope.test1.param` becomes entered text.
- `$scope.test2` remains *null*.

Why `$scope.test2` value does not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If you use ng-model, you have to have a dot in there." Make your
>   model point to an object.property and you'll be good to go.

This happens when child scopes are in play - like child routes or ng-repeats. The child-scope creates it's own value and a name conflict is born.

Better explanation you have here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768720/1081079

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are in a child scope. 
A parent object is known in the child scope but simple variable is recreate for the child.
so when you use $scope.test1 it takes the parent variable,
but when you use $scope.test2 it create new variable to the child so it is not change the parents one. 
to solve this either change $scope.test2 to be also object as $scope.test1
$scope.test2 ={ param: null} 
or use the $parent service:

```
  <input ng-model="$parent.test2">
```