# Why is this <td ng-mouseenter="name='John'"> not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The example below is extremely simple (edited after [*sp00m*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42931313/4927984) correct for the previous example response):

index.html: (part)

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="r in [1,2,3]">
    <td ng-repeat="c in [1,2]" ng-mouseenter="name='John'">
      [{{r}},{{c}}]
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
Hello {{name}}!
```

app.js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

I am expecting the 'World' word being changed to 'John' being shown but nothing occurs when I am mousing over the cell.

I am posting plnkr below to show the problem.
What am I doing wrong?! What am I missing?
Is the problem with AngularJS 1.5.x plnkr is using that does not handle `ng-mouseenter` in `<td>`? Note that ng-repeat is not an issue - when I put manually new row this will not work either.

http://plnkr.co/edit/x1peSJyc50yqa1AM73GZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i had a same problem, i avoid to use the plain scope variables like this `$scope.name`, it may create some problems. so in the above plunker, declare a scope object something like this `$scope.name = {firstName: 'World'}` instead of plain scope variable. Then in html use this `ng-mouseenter="name.firstName='John';"`, and it should work with this `Hello {{name.firstName}}`.

Comment: Dear Santhi - wow. When I changed to a structure it works. A bit frustraiting! I still wonder *why*. Is this the AngularJS bug....? Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz, sorry for late response, using dot notation (means object) is always preferred approach. Please check the answers one by one in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value , you will get a good understanding.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually working, you just haven't defined `alert` in your `$scope`:

```
$scope.alert = function (...) { ... };
```

Comment: Okay, I was expecting the javascript `alert` to be used. What about simple substitution of `'x=10'` and displaying `x`. Actually this does not work for me, so I replaced that with the `alert` one. PS. I will update my original input, but thank you for the quick response!