# ng-change is not working even when ng-model is present in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hi All I have checked for solutions online for my problem but nothing resolved my problem.

HTML5 code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div id="div1" ng-controller = "myCont">
        <input id="txt1" type="text" ng-model="a" ng-change="updateC()">
        <input id="txt2" type="text" ng-model="b">
        <div>a {{a}}</div>
        <div>s {{s}}</div>
        <div>c {{c}}</div>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular_try.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my angularjs code :

```
var myApp= angular.module("myApp",[])

myApp.controller("myCont",["$scope","$rootScope",function($scope,$rootScope)
{
     $scope.s=0;
     $scope.a =0;
     $scope.b=0;
     function updateC()
     {
         $scope.c = $scope.a+20;
     }


     $scope.$watch("c",function(newvalue,oldvalue){
        if(newvalue!=oldvalue)
        {
             $scope.c =$scope.c
        }
   })
}])
```

Could anyone please let me know what is wrong in my code as I am using ng-change with ng-model and also have watch expression for the same but code doesn;t run , tough there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$scope.updateC = function ({
  $scope.c = $scope.a+20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the function to your scope:

```
 $scope.updateC = function() {
     $scope.c = $scope.a+20;
 }
```

Also, to avoid issues with prototypal inheritance, you may want to create an object and bind to properties of that object, instead of binding directly to the scope:

Controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    a: 0, 
    // etc
}
```

View:

```
ng-model="data.a"
```

Or you can switch to the `controller as` syntax. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value) for details.