# JavaScript local scoping: var vs. this

Tags: javascript, scope, scoping

I can't seem to get my head around a specific case of scoping for JavaScript variables. Different from other examples and questions I have found, I am interested in the scoping for nested functions.

I've set up an example at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alpha/a78Qq/7/). The relevant part is the following:

```
function MyObject() {
    var self = this;

    var a = 1;
    this.b = 2;

    var innerMethod = function() {
        //1 and 2: direct reference
        logMessage("a = " + a); // a = 1
        //logMessage("b = " + b); // Error: b is not defined

        //3 and 4: using this
        logMessage("this.a = " + this.a); // this.a = undefined
        logMessage("this.b = " + this.b); // this.b = undefined

        //5 and 6: using self
        logMessage("self.a = " + self.a); // self.a = undefined
        logMessage("self.b = " + self.b); // self.b = 2
    }
}
```

Now, I understand that a reference to `a` directly works. 
I also understand that messages 3 and 4 (`this.a` and `this.b`) will fail because `this` refers to the internal function. I also understand that line 6 works because I save the reference to the original object.

What I do not understand is:

- why aren't messages 1 and 2 working alike?
- why aren't messages 5 and 6 working alike?

Comment: Why would they work alike? Seems like you're analogizing with Java or some other language where the `this` namespace is implicit, which is not the case for JS.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I may be unconscious doing this (pun intended). I fail to understand if the scoping should make variables/members automatically exposed to inner members. It seems that it is not the case, because it's not consistent.

Comment: @Alpha You're comparing variables (`var a = 5;`) with things that are not variables but properties of objects (`this.b = 10;` sets the property `b` of the object that `this` refers to to `10`). These things are not the same and therefore do not behave identically.

Comment: I'm thinking about a simple way to explain it, but basically JS's lexical scope won't automatically expose members to inner members as you've said.

Comment: @Niko Thanks! I think that was the very core of my confusion.

Comment: @Alpha see how 4 changes if you did `innerMethod.call(this);` or `this.method = innerMethod;` and `(new MyObject()).method();`

Comment: @PaulS. Changing the `this` reference is a little out of the scope of the question I believe, but here's a good article if OP or anyone wants to read: [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) by [TJ Crowder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` variable is just that, a variable.  It's visible in the scope of `innerMethod` (which is just a nested function), as `a`, which is how it was declared (ie. JavaScript has lexical scoping rules, inner functions can see variables of the functions they're defined inside of).

`this` isn't the same as the local scope of the `MyObject` constructor.

You've seen that `self` is an alias for `this` of `MyObject`, and that `innerMethod` has overwritten `this` in its own scope.  Still, since `this` is not an alias for function scope, neither `self.a` nor `this.a` will ever work here.

For a more rigorous explanation of lexical scoping you can e.g. start at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

You can read about the execution contexts and identifier resolution rules in the ECMA standard http://es5.github.com/#x10.3

Comment: I'd prefer the term [`VariableEnvironment`](http://es5.github.com/#x10.3) instead of `function scope` in your 3rd paragraph, and state that the reason behind the first paragraph is that JS has [lexical scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope). But very well explained.

Comment: I've incorporated some of your changes, but I'm hesitant to exchange VariableEnvironment for function scope.  Even though it is technically more correct, I believe function scope is a concept that is better known for programmers coming from other languages. I have added your link to the ECMA standard.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with scope, when functions are created they save their surroundings (including variables).

So when `innerMethod` is created, it can see variables `self` and `a`.

An important concept is that the scope is created when the function is declared, instead of when it is called.

In your case 1, `b` is not being declared (the this object is not the same).

In cases 5 and 6, you did not create `self.a`.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that `self` is not equal to `this` in scope of **innerMethod**. `this` is a keyword to reference the owner of the function. For **innerMethod**, it is NOT a instance method, it belongs to the Window.

```
function MyObject() {
    var self = this;

    var innerMethod = function() {
        alert("inner method, self == this?: " + self == this); // false
        alert("inner method: " + this); // [object Window]
        alert("closest constructor name of in prototype chain ?: "+ this.__proto__.constructor.name); // Window
    }

    this.outerMethod = function(){
        innerMethod(); 
        alert("outer method: " + this); // [object MyObject]
        alert("closest constructor name in prototype chain?: "+ this.__proto__.constructor.name); // MyObject
    }
}

var o = new MyObject();
o.outerMethod();
```

You can play at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckwd8vrr/)