# Javascript objects calling function from itself

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

I've been reading Game Design with HTML5 and JavaScript and it introduced me to objects. So after reading the book and working on the projects I decided to take this new found knowledge and integrate objects in my own projects. So here's my question can or should objects call their own functions? For example:

```
var someObject = {
    start: function() {
        check();
    },
    check: function() {
        console.log("Check!");
    }
};

someObject.start();
```

The book did show an example with a timer that does this:

```
var timer = {
    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);
    },
    tick: function() {
        console.log('tick!');
    }
};
```

In the example with timer object it makes a reference to self in order to call the internal function, so does this mean I should use self to call internal functions or is this the proper way to do this with objects? Or best practices? Thanks in advance.

```
var someObject = {
    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.check();
    },
    check: function() {
        console.log("Check!");
    }
};

someObject.start();
```

Comment: The reason they use it in the `setTimeout` example is because its callback is executed in the global scope, so the value of `this` in the `setTimeout` callback is `window`. In order to keep a reference to the original object, you have to use that method (of storing it in `self`) or some form of using `Function.bind()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JavaScript names are [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047491/716118), so whenever a name (variable) is encountered in a script, the JavaScript runtime must search up the scopes from where the function was defined.

At the point of definition, this function:

```
start: function() {
    check();
}
```

doesn't have access to any `check` function in its outer scope. Declaring `self` and binding it to `this` is a technique used to deal with the (somewhat interesting) [intricacies of referring to the **current object** in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) (because the example code uses `window.setInterval`).

To reference a function within the current object, it is enough to use `this`.

```
var someObject = {
    start: function() {
        this.check();
    },
    check: function() {
        console.log("Check!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's javascript function context, each time you create a function, you create a new context (scope).

In `setInterval()` function you create a new scope, so `this` no longer refer as the same `this` above:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function() {
    self.tick();
}, 1000);
```

You can also manually bind the proper context of your function with [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (so you don't need `self` anymore):

```
setInterval(function() {
    this.tick();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

---

More informations:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html

Answer (score 1):

The point of declaring and initializing a variable like "self" is to deal with the fact that the value of `this` is determined anew upon each function call. When you've got a function nested inside another function, and that inner function needs access to the value of `this` from the outer context, then `this` must be preserved in another variable — "self" in your case. (The name of that variable is unimportant of course.)

In your sample code:

```
var timer = {
    start: function() {
        var self = this;
        window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);
    },
    tick: function() {
        console.log('tick!');
    }
};
```

that function passed in to `setInterval()` needs to use the value of `this` from the "start" function. When that interval timer function is called, however, `this` is set to something else (either the global context or `null` in "strict" mode).  Thus, by saving the value of `this` in the context where that interval timer function is instantiated, its code can use it to access the timer object.

In your second example, declaring and initializing a "self" variable doesn't hurt anything, but it's unnecessary. Sometimes it's handy however, just to clarify the code, though of course a more meaningful name than "self" would be a good idea.

Comment: That's not what is doing in the second example though

Answer (score 0):

of course an object can and should call it's own functions, this is the only way to emulate OOP in javascript. I would say that the practice that the book is using, `self = this` is bad  since `this` can just be used by itself, however in the first example it is used to preserve the value of this which would otherwise be the `this` of the function itself not the outer class

Comment: "emulate"; just keep telling yourself that, maybe click your heels together while you say it...

Comment: There are multiple reasons for doing `var self = this`; a completely unrelated reason is to make script compression more efficient.

Comment: @voithos read the whole answer I only said the second use was bad