# Getting a weird number when getting an access to ID attibute of input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get a value of id attribute for an input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="heading1" class="alert-heading" value="aaa" />
```

In order to to this, I wrote this code.

```
var alertHeading = $(".alert-heading");

alertHeading.on('blur', function(){
    var headingId = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(headingId); // outputs 2943. I'm expecting "heading1".
});
```

But, I get a weird number when I get an access to id although I'm expecting to get a "heading1".

This is the code that I'm working on right now.

```
var alertHeading = $(".alert-heading");

alertHeading.on('blur', function(){

    var key = alertMode.val();

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {

        var background = backgroundPage.background;

        var alertObject = background.getStorage(key);

        //(EDITED)Oh I think $(this)here no longer points to the input element!!
        var headingId = $(this).attr("id");

        console.log(headingId); // outputs 2943. I'm expecting "heading1".

    });

})
```

Please help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `$(this)` by `$(".alert-heading")`, as `$(this)` is probably not what you think it is

Comment: By the way `$alertHeading` is a nice var name because it notes that it is a jquery object.

Comment: it works fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/janith/7S5ud/

Comment: Have you checked it properly ? because when i m trying its working fine and give me output as you want. wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explaining this in ECMAScript terms, every time control [enters a function](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) a new [Execution Context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3) is created. Each execution context has its own `thisBinding`, hence you need to store a reference to the outer context's `this` reference so that you can access it through [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1047454/1331430).

```
alertHeading.on('blur', function(){
    //[...]
    var el = this; //copy the `this` reference to a variable
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        // [...]
        var headingId = el.id; //access outer scope's this

    });
});
```

I'm using `el.id` which access the `id` property of the DOM element referenced by `el`. It is good practice to work with the DOM instead of HTML `attr`ibutes whenever you can.

---

The lexical scope trick is the most common approach but there are several ways to fix this.

In ES5, it is also possible to [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `this` reference of a function object:

```
alertHeading.on('blur', function(){
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        // [...]
        var headingId = this.id; //2. Now it has the same this as outer scope

    }.bind(this)); //1. The onblur's `this` is bound to the bgpage callback
});
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out good practice with `DOMElement.id` property.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save `this` in a closure variable:

```
alertHeading.on('blur', function(){

    var key = alertMode.val();
    var that = this;

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        var background = backgroundPage.background;
        var alertObject = background.getStorage(key);
        var headingId = that.id;
        console.log(headingId);
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(that).attr("id");` use `that.id;`