# When is a identifier in a lambda bound?

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp

I am reading SICP. Something is confusing me. These are written by myself to test.

```
;This procedure bind a symbol `f` to a lambda, and that lambda is not evaluated.
(define f
  (lambda () x))

;create a frame which binds x to 10, and then evaluate f, should return 10.
(let ((x 10))
    (f))
```

But DrRacket does not accept it.

> x: unbound identifier in module in: x

Comment: Which chapter is that code from?

Comment: @sepp2k. That code is written by myself. I'm reading chapter 3.2 *The Environment Model of Evaluation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing here is that `x` is a free variable. Expressions in Racket (and most languages) can not have free variables (called a "closed term")[2].

If you would have free variables, as `x` is in your example, you would need to call the function in an environment in which some occurence of `x` is bound. You achieve that by calling it in a `let` that binds `x`.

However, Scheme is lexically scoped[1], which means that it captures the variables from the environment in which it is defined. But you don't have an `x` defined in the scope in which your lambda is defined. Hence the error.

Some reading to enlighten this:

[1] Static vs Lexical scoping: [Static (Lexical) Scoping vs Dynamic Scoping (Pseudocode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394089/static-lexical-scoping-vs-dynamic-scoping-pseudocode)

[2] Free variables : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Answer (score 2):

It's because of lexical scoping.

```
(define f
  (lambda () x))
```

Since `x` is not in the lexical scope it **has to be a global variable**. Thus you can do the following:

```
(define x 10)
(f) ;=> 10
```

To make it a lexical variable it has to already exist at creation time:

```
(define f
  (let ((x 10))
    (lambda () x)))
```

In this example, since `x` is a bound lexical variable the `x` in the lambda is the same since the lambda inherits the environment from where **it's evaluated**.

Yes! A `lambda` expression **is evaluated** so that it becomes a procedure object and `define` assignes the global symbol `f` to that object.

To prove that try to apply a list structure:

```
('(lambda (x) x) 10) ; gets error 'application: not a procedure'
```

In a LISP that has dynamic scoping the procedures doesn't have environments and the environment is takes from the runtime at call time:

```
(define (test)
  some-value)

(define (call-test)
  (let ((some-value 10))
    (test))) ; => 10

(test) ; => error (unbound variable)
```

As you might see with dynamic scope it's difficult to tell if a procedure is correct or not as the environment it has when called changes for each call. Lexical scoping is also much easier for a compiler to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme has lexical scoping. What this means is that when the body of a lambda is evaluated, it is evaluated using the environment from where the lambda was created, not from where it was called.

So while there exists an `x` variable when you call `f`, that does not matter because Scheme looks for a definition of `x` in the environment where you defined `f` where no such variable exists.