# are anonymous functions dynamically scoped?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I read in Java also that anonymous functions introduces a new scope within the enclosing function whereas lambda expressions are block-local.Does it mean the above.I am confused with the following example:

```
var timer = {
    seconds: 0,
    start() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.seconds++
        }, 1000)
    }
}
// When an item is searched, it starts from the anonymous function
// and this doesn't mean the same as parent this.
// This means that we can access this .seconds by first going to
// its enclosing function in the arrow expression.
timer.start()

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(timer.seconds)
}, 3500)
```

Here this.seconds will introduce a new scope of this in the enclosing function if it is an anonymous function.Am I right?
[Static (Lexical) Scoping vs Dynamic Scoping (Pseudocode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394089/static-lexical-scoping-vs-dynamic-scoping-pseudocode)

Comment: The `this` keyword is not called "scope" if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous function" and "lamda expression"? Function expressions and arrow functions can both be anonymous.

Comment: Kindly explain me something

Comment: Yes,can you explain me scoping in classes

Comment: What does this have to do classes? Of course I could explain you anything, but I won't if you don't tell what you don't understand. Put some comments in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "*When an item is searched*"? And by "anonymous function", you refer to the `() => { … }` one?

Comment: an anonymous function cannot access its outer elements but arrow expression can,But I read in some book about lexical scoping of arrow expressions

Comment: Every function creates its own scope, no matter if it is anonymous or an arrow function, or not, and they always can access the outer scope. Scope is something you literally write to the script file, and it can't be programmatically changed.

Comment: Thank you very much ,but kindly explain about the first comment

Comment: @DeepakGupta I still don't get what you mean by "outer elements". Variables?

Comment: Probably you've a confusion between the scope and the context. Maybe [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is `this`. Arrow functions do not change the value of `this`, while functions created with the `function` keyword do.

That is why there is a difference between the code you have above and the following code:

```
var timer = {
    seconds: 0,
    start() {
        setInterval(function(){
            this.seconds++
        }, 1000)
    }
}
// When an item is searched, it starts from the anonymous function
// and this doesn't mean the same as parent this.
// This means that we can access this .seconds by first going to
// its enclosing function in the arrow expression.
timer.start()

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(timer.seconds)
}, 3500)
```

In this code, `function(){` overwrites the value of `this` to itself, so there is no seconds variable anymore.

There is no difference in scope (which variables the functions have access to) between traditional anonymous functions and arrow functions, only that traditional anonymous functions create a new `this` and arrow functions do not.