# Do mainstream programming languages today mostly use dynamic or static(lexical) scope?

Tags: c++, c, scope, programming-languages

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394089/static-lexical-scoping-vs-dynamic-scoping-pseudocode) question, and I think I've understood the most upvoted answer, but he said

> since basically every programming language in wide use today uses
>   lexical scoping

I also heard this from [coursera programming language](https://www.coursera.org/learn/programming-languages/home/welcome), but here's a simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 1;

void fun(){
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

void dummy1(){
    x = 2;
    fun();
}

void dummy2(){
    x = 3;
    fun();
}


int main(){

    x = 4;

    fun();
    dummy1();
    dummy2();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
4
2
3
```

C++ have exactly the same behavior, so I think C and C++ are dynamic scoped language, are they? And is it real that most programming languages use static scope?

Comment: The full sentence in that answer is *This is likely a very unfamiliar concept, since basically every programming language in wide use today (except perhaps emacs lisp) uses lexical scoping* which would make you think that includes C and C++(those would be pretty hard to forget if they were different)

Comment: All of those functions are using the same global variable. This isn't showing dynamic scoping.

Comment: Dynamic scoping is when you introduce a new variable (i.e. `int x = 3`) and functions you call can see it. Here you aren't introducing any new variables but using the same global one.

Comment: You only have one x definition here, so *static lexical scoping* and *dynamic scoping* would behave the same anyway. And both C and C++ use *static lexical scoping*.

Comment: I really think you should widen your language vocabulary and investigate LISP, SNOBOL, BASIC and ADA.  Not all languages have scoping rules.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for your advice! I've touched C/C++ and a little bit python, and am learning SML to understand some common basics of programming language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is not dynamic scoping. You aren't introducing any new variables but using the same global one. If C and C++ had dynamic scoping then this (note that each `x` is a new variable):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 1;

void fun(){
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

void dummy1(){
    int x = 2;
    fun();
}

void dummy2(){
    int x = 3;
    fun();
}


int main(){

    int x = 4;

    fun();
    dummy1();
    dummy2();

    return 0;
}
```

would output

```
4
2
3
```

but instead [it outputs](https://repl.it/repls/VividLittleMedian)

```
1
1
1
```

Since `fun()` is always using the same global `x` initialized to 1. This is because C and C++ use static lexical scoping.

Comment: Another helpful point to illustrate the difference between dynamic scoping and making everything global, would be to add another call to `fun()` after the calls to the `dummy` functions. With dynamic scoping the output should then be `4,2,3,4` whereas OP's version with only a global variable would produce `4,2,3,3`.

Comment: If dynamic, output should be `4 2 3` or `4 3 2`?

Comment: Oops, yeah it should be `4 2 3`. I got the order wrong. Edited.