# Javascript: scope of variable

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

For a function, does it get the variable scope during the declaration, or before the run time?

I tried the first part of code below and it doesn't work. The second part works.  Can somebody shed some insight on the difference?

```
//// does not work
function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    let v1 = 1;
    a();
}

b();

//// does work

function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    a();
}

let v1 = 1;
b();
```

Comment: lexical scope is set at declaration, what we call closure. if you declare a inside of b in the first case, it would work fine.

Comment: this is an example of dynamic vs static (lexical) scoping. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395580/989121 for the explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `let` keyword gives a variable block-level scope, meaning the `v1` variable in `b()` is only usable inside `b()`. `a()` does not know what `v1` is.

```
//// does not work
function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    let v1 = 1;
    a();
}

b();
```

In this example, `v1` is being set in the global scope, so all your functions will recognize it.

```
//// does work

function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    a();
}

let v1 = 1;
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, Let's Look at this:

```
//// does not work
function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    let v1 = 1;
    a();
}

b();
```

In the above snippet of code, you have 2 functions (**a()** and **b()**) and invoke the method **b()** from your "main" function (which is unnamed but there).  In a(), you try to directly access a local-scope variable from **b()** - which you can't.

```
//// does work

function a() {
    console.log(v1);
}

function b() {
    a();
}

let v1 = 1;
b();
```

So in this snippet of code, you also have **a()** and **b()** - as well as a variable **v1**.  Since this is declared in the public space (before invoking **b()** - which then invokes **a()**), it is also available within the methods that you invoke.