# Set data object to value from Promise in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuejs3

I'm trying to set the `data()` value in a `Vue` instance to a value retrieved from a Promise that is returned from a `mongodb api` call. I'm able to retrieve the data I'm trying to implement, however am struggling to use it in the `data()` field so that I can access it in the template.

Some of the solutions I've found from `vue2` don't seem to work in this instance. Thanks in advance.

**Vue**

```
<template>
  <Article :title=posts[0].title></Article>  // Another Vue component
</template>

let stories;

export default {
       data() {
            return {
                posts: {}
            }
       },
        methods: {
            loadPosts() {
                stories = getPosts(); // makes an api request to a mongodb that returns a Promise
                stories.then(function(response) {
                    this.posts = response.posts;
                    console.log(response.posts[0].title); // "My Post Title"
                });

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadPosts();
        }
}
```

The error I receive says

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'posts' of undefined

in reference to `this.posts = ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` get the `window` reference as you are using `dynamic` scope, use `lexical scope binding` to get `this` as `Vue`

For your specific reference and eagerness to read more about scopes - follow this [Static (Lexical) Scoping vs Dynamic Scoping (Pseudocode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394089/static-lexical-scoping-vs-dynamic-scoping-pseudocode)

For lexically binding use `arrow-function`

```
loadPosts() {
  stories = getPosts(); 
  stories.then(response => {
      this.posts = response.posts;
      console.log(response.posts[0].title); // "My Post Title"
  });
 }
```