Static (Lexical ) scoping outputs and Dynamic Scoping outputs(We were asked to Pretend if it uses Dynamic scoping In C )
This is the Code from our teacher
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1, b = 2;

void C() {
    int a = 50;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    D();
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}

void D() {
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    a = 3; b = 4;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    E();
}

void E() {
    int b = 6;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    a = 7; b = 8;
}

int main() {
    int a = 20, b = 30;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    C();
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    D();
    return 0;
}

We were asked to find out outputs of this code with :

Static scoping

Dynamic scoping


And these were the answers given by teacher
Static scoping:
20,30
50,2
1,2
3,4
3,6
50,4
20,30
7,4
3,4
3,6
Dynamic scoping:
20,30
50,30
50,30
3,4
3,6
7,4
20,4
20,4
3,4
3,6
I understand the static scoping outputs but I can’t understand how we got the outputs in the case of dynamic scoping.
I need help in verifying if these are correct or not and if not then what should be the correct output.
I tried doing it on my own, asked the teacher but couldn’t get a reply because he had other class in other town.

What does your teacher mean by "static" and "dynamic" scope?

I believe these are archaic terms which isn't very relevant to the C language, since it always uses "static scoping". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394089/static-lexical-scoping-vs-dynamic-scoping-pseudocode. I'd ask the teacher why you need to learn about such ancient terms without relevance in modern computer science. It would probably be time better spent to learn how the C language actually works, than to ponder how it would work if the dinosaurs changed the rules back in the 1970s.

Also, scope is a formal term in C with an entirely different meaning, making these nonsense terms extra bad to teach students.

It appears that by "dynamic scoping" your teachers might have meant that as if each function would have been inserted as a scope in main function. If you do this, it seems to give same results as in your example:
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1, b = 2;

int main() {
    int a = 20, b = 30;
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    //C();
    {
        int a = 50;
        printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
        //D();
        {
            printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
            a = 3; b = 4;
            printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
            //E();
            {
                int b = 6;
                printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
                a = 7; b = 8;
            }
        }
        printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
    //D();
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
        a = 3; b = 4;
        printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
        //E();
        {
            int b = 6;
            printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
            a = 7; b = 8;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

In C we don't use terms like "static scope" or "dynamic scope". If this learning course was purely about learning C language, then this is a wrong way to teach it. Rather than inventing new terms, teacher should have given you the sample code that I wrote here instead. This way students don't have to invent non-existing rules to reason with the code.
I might be more forgiving to the teacher if this course was about advanded topic like language design, but even then I would have expected them to give definitions of these terms to the students.

One comment mentioned that these terms may have originated from geeksforgeeks website. I don't really like that site, as I have previously found multiple mistakes or misinformation in there.

I think they originate from archaic computer science theory dated 1960s or so, but a certain big country in Asia stubbornly insists on teaching their students outdated crap. And students from that particular country are behind geeksforgeeks, giving said crap a prominent place on that site.

"Dynamic" scoping looks up a name in the chain of calls at runtime. That is, the scope of a "local" variable extends into any functions it calls.
As was discovered pretty soon after the first Lisp was released, it easily creates a mess of things, but despite what many think it can actually be quite useful in certain very limited cases - for instance for "hiding" a global variable in order to make a temporary change to a value.
(This code is not an example of such a case.)
The feature is still available as "special" variables in Common Lisp.
It goes like this (using the :: from C++ to indicate a variable's scope):
global: int a = 1, b = 2
  main: int a = 20, b = 30 (main::a, main::b - makes the globals inaccessible)
    print main::a, main::b  -- 20, 30
    C: int a = 50 (C::a)
       print C::a, main::b  -- 50, 30
       D: print C::a, main::b  -- 50, 30
          C::a = 3
          main::b = 4
          print C::a, main::b  -- 3, 4
          E: int b = 6 (E::b)
             print C::a, E::b  -- 3, 6
             C::a = 7 
             E::b = 8
       print C::a, main::b -- 7, 4
    print main::a, main::b -- 20, 4
    D: print main::a, main::b -- 20, 4
       main::a = 3
       main::b = 4
       print main::a, main::b  -- 3, 4
       E: int b = 6 (E::b)
          print main::a, E::b -- 3, 6
          main::a = 7
          E::b = 8       
              


Good answer. I must add one thing: the C language doesn't have an equivalent of "dynamic scope" (in the sense explained in this answer, which seems consistent with the output provided by the teacher). There is no way of "setting C for using dynamic scoping" (and that's not just a terminology issue)..

@DiegoFerruchelli Nobody has made any such claim.

The OP assumed it was possible: "We were asked to find out outputs of this code with: 1. Static scoping 2. Dynamic scoping". We talked about this in the question "staging area".
