# scope vs variable environment in execution context

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

What is the difference between scope and variable environment in the execution context of Javascript? Why do they need scope when they already have a variable environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948198/variable-environment-vs-lexical-environment/54673945

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable Environment vs lexical environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948198/variable-environment-vs-lexical-environment)