# Difference between Lexical Environments and Environment Records in modern ecmaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I try to understand how closure is working under the hood. So I've read a lot of documentation and so many different websites.

Then I read this [Variable Environment vs lexical environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948198/variable-environment-vs-lexical-environment#)

And in old documentation (2011) https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-10.2

there are two different things, LE and ER.

But in modern https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-environment-records

There is only one, environment record, and description of it is very similar to the old describe of lexical environments/

So, I am really confusing. Does LE still exist for modern javaScript (ecmaScript 6+)? What the difference between LE and ER?

Comment: It looks like LE and ER were just folded into a single type. The spec seems to say that a LE has a reference to an outer LE, and now the ER itself has such a reference. However, that difference isn't really relevant to know/learn how closures work: (1) Environments are nested and a "child" environment has a reference to its "parent" environment. If a variable isn't found in a child, it's looked for in the parent, etc. (2) A function has a reference to the environment it was created in. Variables not declared inside the function are looked up there.

Comment: Note that this is all just specification terminology. Nothing *changed* (other than new features being added). it's just the terms that the specification used to describe behavior were tweaked a bit. Closures still work like they always have.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first go through the definition of `Lexical Environment` & `Environment Record` as per different versions of ECMAScript Specification.

From [**ES2015**](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/) till [**ES2020**](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/) Specification:-

### 1. Lexical Environment:

- A Lexical Environment is a **specification type** used to define the association of Identifiers to specific variables and functions based upon the lexical nesting structure of ECMAScript code.
- A lexical environment is consists of two components:

  1. `Environment Record`
  2. `Reference` to outer environment

### 2. Environment Record:

- An Environment Record records the **identifier bindings** that are created within the scope of its associated Lexical Environment. It is referred to as the Lexical Environment's EnvironmentRecord.

Conceptual look using pseudo-code:

```
context.environment = {
    // storage
    environmentRecord: { 
    <identifier> : <value>
    <identifier> : <value>
    }
    // reference to the parent environment
    outer: <...> 
}
```

**Note:** - The `[[Environment]]` created inside Execution Context is of type **Lexical Environment**[[refer ES2020]](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects)

---

According to [**12th Edition ECMAScript2021**](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/) Specification:

### 1. Environment Record

- A Environment Record is a **specification type** used to define the association of Identifiers to specific variables and functions, based upon the lexical nesting structure of ECMAScript code.
- Every Environment Record has an `[[OuterEnv]]` field, which is either null or a reference to an outer Environment Record.

Conceptual look using pseudo-code:

```
context.environment = {
    // storage
    <identifier> : <value>
    <identifier> : <value>
    // reference to the parent environment
    outer: <...>
}
```

**Note:** - The `[[Environment]]` created inside Execution Context is of type **Environment Record**[[refer ES2021]](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects)

---

Let's also understand the `Structure of execution context`

### Execution Context:

- An Execution Context is a specification device that is used to track the runtime evaluation of the code.
- To keeps the track of execution progress of its associated code, it needs various **state components** like `LexicalEnvironment`, `VariableEnvironment`, etc.

In pseudo-code:

```
ExecutionContext = {
    VariableEnvironment: { ... },
    LexicalEnvironment: { ... },
    // other components
}
```

**Note:**

| Till ES2020 | From ES2021 |
| --- | --- |
| - The `LexicalEnvironment component` and `VariableEnvironment component` of an execution context are always **Lexical Environments**[[refer ES2020]](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#table-23) | - The `LexicalEnvironment component` and `VariableEnvironment` components of an execution context are always **Environment Records**[[refer ES2021]](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#table-23) |

So, **Yes** `Lexical Environment` still exists for Modern JavaScript[ES2021] but now the **[[Environment]]** created is of **type** `Environment Records`.

Comment: Sooo, in a nutshel, Lexical Environments and Environment Records are now considered to be the same thing?