# How a function knows when it's executed within a certain scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, sentry

Looking at this example from the Sentry docs - how does the `Sentry.captureException` know that it's being called within `Sentry.withScope`?

The `Sentry.captureException` method will need to access the parameters assigned to that scope such as the user. But no reference of the scope is passed to the function.

```js
    Sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
        scope.setUser(someUser);
        Sentry.captureException(error);
    });
```

The only way I can imagine to pass data between the two functions is via some kind of `try catch` trickery. I don't see another way that the `Sentry.captureException` can know about the parent scope and the parameters associated with that scope.

Comment: [What is the 'Execution Context' in JavaScript exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/), [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/)

Comment: Maybe a bit more up-to-date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73355400/1169519 and http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/#environment

Comment: @Teemu That's a different "scope" than the Sentry term

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how the `Sentry` object is implemented. For example, it could be achieved with this:

```js
class ScopedSentry {
  withScope(f) {
    f({setUser: function(user) {
      this.user = user;
    }.bind(this)});
  }
  captureException(error) {
    console.error(error, this.user);
  }
}
var Sentry = new ScopedSentry();
Sentry.withScope(function(scope) {
  scope.setUser("someUser");
  Sentry.captureException("error");
});
```

Comment: This is good but it creates a single global scope rather than a local scope. So after `setUser` is called, all `captureException` will return the user even if they're not called within the `withScope`

Comment: No, it creates a scope that is bound to the individual `ScopedSentry`. If you have another `Sentry2 = new ScopedSentry()`, each will have its own scope.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the actual library uses one actual static `Sentry` object which I think poses the real challenge. There's no value in `withScope` if you have to use a specific `ScopedSentry`

Comment: I think this one needs a real javascript expert to solve

Comment: @AdamCarter Only you need to become an expert is to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) and the posts and articles I and Andreas have linked in the comments above.

Comment: @AdamCarter Just do `try { f(…); } finally { this.user = undefined; }` if you don't want to keep the value after the `withScope` call

Comment: What if `f` is asynchronous?