# Will the reference of an object passed into a function as a parameter change?

Tags: javascript

Why is `a.y` undefined after I change the reference of `a` in the function?

```
var a = { x : 1 };
a = { y : 2 };
function _change(b) {
    b = { y : 3 };
    return b;
}

_change(a);
document.write(a.y);   // undefined
document.write(a.x);   //1
```

And the below code behaves differently

```
var a = {x:1};
var b={y:1};
b=a;
a.x //undefined
a.y //1
```

Why?

Comment: `a.x` is `undefined` here, not `a.y`.

Comment: Neither of the blocks of code that you show would give the outputs that your comments say they would. (As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j2g68rf9/) for the first block.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this down and understand the variables in different [lexical scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope).

`a` in the global lexical scope:

```
var a = {x:1};
a = {y:2};
```

The above initialization would resolve to:

```
a = {y:2};

//hence at this global lexical scope 
//`lexicalscope = {"a":{y:2}};`
```

Now, let us see the variables inside the lexical scope of the function:

```
function _change(b){
       // at the function's `lexicalEnvironment = {"b":{y:2}}`
        b= { y:3};
       //  at this point `lexicalEnvironment = {"b":{y:3}}`
        return b;  //returned {y:3}.
    }
```

When the function is invoked with `a` as its parameter.

```
_change(a); // obtained {y:3} but not captured.
```

I would love to include the beautiful explanation for why the value of `a` does not change outside the scope of the function in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) here, but, do not want to duplicate the original answer. Would like to share the relevant part though,

> *In practical terms, this means that if you change the parameter itself (as with a), 
>   that won't affect the item that was fed
>   into the parameter. But if you change the INTERNALS of the parameter, such as b.y = 3,
>   that will propagate back up.*

Again, printing their values in the global lexical scope.

```
console.log(a.y); // still in the global lexical environment a.y = 2;
console.log(a.x); // `a.x` is undefined in the global Lexical Environment.
```

Comment: What I dont understand is why is the reference of the 'a' not changed  to {y:2} when i called the function. Please could you elaborate on this. Thanks

Comment: @user2713706 - Please see my edited answer. And read the informative answer i have linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're totally changing the a object `{x:1}` with `{y:2}` so there's no x property in a object.

What I think is you need to use like this:

```
var a = {x:1};
a.y = 2;//assign y = 2 in a oject.
```

So, do the same manner in your change function.

Answer (score 1):

---

### First Block

This is what I get by running the code line by line:

```js
var a = {x:1};  // <-- sets a to the object {x:1}
a = {y:2}; // <-- sets a to the object {y:2}, so it no longer has a.x = 1

function _change(b)
{
    b= { y:3};
    return b;
}

_change(a); // <-- this doesn't change a, it returns {y: 3} but it is not used

document.write(a.y); // 2 actually
document.write(a.x); // undefined
```

---

Let's try to understand it...

```
var a = {x:1};
```

There you declare the variable `a`, you create an object `{x:1}`, and set `a` to that object.

```
a = {y:2};
```

There you create a new object `{y:2}` and set `a` to it. So `a` no longer has the first object.

So... when you ask for `a.y` it has `2`, and when you ask for `a.x` it is `undefined` because the object `{y:2}` doesn't have `x`. Remember that you replaced the object of the variable `a` from being `{x:1}` to `{y:2}`.

---

Instead you can add fields on the fly, like this:

```js
var a = {x:1};  // <-- sets a to the object {x:1}
a.y = 2; // <-- Add a field y to the object of the variable a, it has the value 2

function _change(b)
{
    b.y = 3; // <-- actually modify the object, now the field y has value 3
    return b;
}

_change(a);

document.write(a.y); // 3
document.write(a.x); // 1
```

---

### Second Block

Again, I get a different result than you... I wonder where are you running your code.

```js
var a = {x:1}; // <-- sets a to the object {x:1}
var b={y:1}; // <-- sets b to the object {y:1}
b=a; // <-- now sets b to the object {x:1} - nobody has {y:1} anymore
document.write(a.x); // 1 actually
document.write(a.y); // undefined
```

Ok, so when you say `b=a` you are making the variable `b` to point to the same object as the variable `a`. By doing so, the variable `b` no longer points to the object `{x:1}`... which is irrelevant because you are not using the variable `b` anyway.

The variable `a` had `{x:1}` all along, and you can see it doesn't have any field `y` defined.

---

It seems to be that you believe that assigning an object somehow fuses the objects, resulting in both sides having a combination of the fields... if you intend to do that, you may be interested in [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically).