# Golang bolt access to value

Tags: go

```
var value_variable
        // Access data from within a read-only transactional block.
    db.View(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        v := tx.Bucket([]byte("people")).Get([]byte("john"))
        fmt.Printf("John's last name is %s.\n", v)
        return nil
    })
```

How to assign john value to value_variable?

Answer (score 2):

Since Go is [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047491/46871), you can assign `value_variable` inside the function you pass into `View`:

```
var value_variable []byte

// Access data from within a read-only transactional block.
db.View(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
    v := tx.Bucket([]byte("people")).Get([]byte("john"))
    value_variable = v // <----- ASSIGN IT HERE
    fmt.Printf("John's last name is %s.\n", v)
    return nil
})
```