# JavaScript PubSub Pattern: What is happening with the context of "this", why is it lost?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I am starting to get my feet wet using the publish/subscribe pattern in JavaScript, but now facing a problem I don't understand.

Take the following scenario:

On button click, a message is emitted, this works.

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    PubSub.publish('topic', data);
});
```

In an other part of my application, I pick up this message:

```
function MyObj() {
    this.eventLog = [];
    var token = PubSub.subscribe('topic', this.logger);
};

MyObj.prototype.logger = function(message, data) {
    this.eventLog.push(data);
}
```

Here I want to store the published data in the `eventLog` property of the `MyObj` object. Unfortunately, this isn't working:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventLog' of undefined
```

So it seems like the context of `this` is lost – when I do `console.log(this)`, the `window` object is logged.

I know `this` can be tricky for beginners, but until now I was always able to understand what is happening, but this leaves me completely puzzled. Of course `MyObj` gets initialized before the message is published, so I don't see any problem here. Could somebody explain to me please what is happening here?

Comment: The binding of `this` has to do with the way a function is **called**. When you pass `this.logger` as a callback parameter, all that the called function sees is the reference to the function, and the original relationship to `this` is completely lost at that point. Use `.bind()` to create a wrapper function to fix the value of `this`.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for explaining what is happening – I unterstand it now. Also I finally managed to understand how to use `bind()`, really exiting stuff!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
 PubSub.subscribe('topic', this.logger.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify/explain the observed behaviour - JavaScript uses lexical scoping, so the **this** keyword is bound to the most inner scope of the usage. Depending where (in which function and parent of the function and/or object) the **this** keyword is used, **it is** a different object.

In your case when calling the `this.eventLog` in your `MyObj` this is referring to the `MyObj`. But in the part

```
MyObj.prototype.logger = function(message, data) {
    this.eventLog.push(data);
}
```

the **this** keyword is called *in the scope* of the `window` object (parent is the window object) and that is why you see it when printed instead of `MyObj`.

Technically the context of **this** is always pushed/saved in a stack, so the context is not *lost*, but the current context is popped/retrieved from the stack regarding the current scope.

This behaviour is very well (also visually) described in this article [Quirksmode - The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).
A few good examples can also be found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope).

Comment: The value of `this` really has nothing at all to do with scoping rules.