# Jquery: scope in a .when .done function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to access a variable inside a .when.done function. here's the example:

```
var colviews = {
    1: true,
    2: true,
    3: false
}

$.when(  // run only -when- these script get loaded
    $.getScript( "/mckinney_images/jquery.tablesorter.all.js" )).done(function(){

    $(function(){
        console.log(colviews); // How do I get the colviews variable here?
    });

});
```

I have a basic understanding of scope but not sure how it applies inside a when function.

Comment: `colviews` is a global variable so it could be access everywhere (but do not depend your local classes on global variables)

Comment: Btw, you don't need that `$.when` at all, just use `$.getScript(…).done(…);`

Comment: Your code most certainly does not reproduce the problem you claim it does. `colviews` will absolutely be available on the line where you write `console.log`.

Comment: @meagar: Did he actually claim that it was not?

Comment: @Bergi Yes? How else can you interpret this question? The line `console.log(colviews); // How do I get the colviews variable here?` seemingly indicates that the `console.log` is failing to print the expected value. This is *not* due to the variable being inaccessible as the comment implies.

Comment: @meagar: Rather literally "*I understand how scope works, but am not sure what (if anything) is different inside a `$.when`*". But I'm not trying to argue :-)

Comment: @meagar `colviews` is available in his code, but it itself has a problem that has been corrected in my post.

Comment: @MaxZoom No, your post is unnecessary and adds nothing new. You do not need to "pass in" `colviews`, it's already in scope.

Comment: @MaxZoom what do you think "invalid" means in this case? There is nothing wrong with that variable or its declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a basic understanding of scope

Good! So you know [what scope is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1047454/1048572), [how closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) and [how `var` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572).

> …but not sure how it applies inside a when function.

Simple: It's no different! Yes, the `done` callback function is [invoked asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572), but that doesn't change how scope works.
You just *are* getting the `colviews` variable there successfully (if it doesn't log the expected value, that means it was overwritten elsewhere or the callback is never called because `$.getScript` failed).

`$.when` does no magic (and in fact, in your example it's not needed at all, your code works the same when you omit it).

Comment: @MaxZoom: Not sure whether I got this wrong, but my claim is that his code is already working. No need to improve anything (neglecting the minor `$.when` quibble). OP asked for understanding, not for fixing anything afaiks.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out later on in the day.