# Lexical environment and Initialization of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I searched for what is lexical environment  in javascript function.But I didn't get any proper answer for that on the result.Can anyone simply explain what is a lexical environment and how does it relate with Initialization of functions .

Cheers !!!

Comment: I'd suggest you read the first four hits in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+lexical+environment) for "Javascript lexical environment".  The lexical environment affects the operation of functions (it tells you which variables are "in scope" and which are not), but I'm not sure how it has anything to do with "initialization of functions" or what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is lexical scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)