# Polymer Selenium Test Accessing Sub-Element Data

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

In a firebase-login element I have

```
<paper-button id="btnLogin" data-dialog="login-modal" on-tap="toggleLogin">
    <iron-icon icon="account-box"></iron-icon>
    Login
</paper-button>
```

Where toggleLogin calls:

```
toggleLogin: function() {this.$.loginModal.toggle();},
```

In the Polymer test suite I am using:

```
Polymer.dom(element.root).querySelector('#btnLogin').click();
```

But Selenium is giving me the error of:

```
this.$.loginModal.toggle is not a function
```

Long story short, how can I click the button and check the modal pops up?

Note: Polymer team's test looks like:

```
Polymer.dom(myEl.root).querySelector('button').click()
```

Since they are naming their element myEl instead of element and looking for the button tag instead of the tag with id of btnLogin I felt that my solution was suitable. What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

While looking at the bind event I still have not gotten things working.

CODE:

```
var btnLogin = Polymer.dom(myEl.root).querySelector('#btnLogin');
// This does the same thing as
// var btnLogin = element.$.btnLogin;
btnLogin.click.bind(btnLogin);
```

The above code allows me to move past the line but does not actually toggle the dialog. I am not sure why. When I add in `click()` instead of `click` it gives me the `this.$.loginModal.toggle() is not defined` error that I have been struggling with.

UPDATE:

Still have not found a good answer to this. Was looking into some code that may help and found the submenu element that wants to know information about it's content elements. I will include their testing below.

CODE:

```
  suite('<paper-submenu>', function() {
    var menu,
        sub1, sub2, sub3,
        collapse1, collapse2, collapse3,
        trigger1, trigger2, trigger3;
    setup(function() {
      menu = fixture('basic');
      sub1 = menu.querySelectorAll('paper-submenu')[0];
      sub2 = menu.querySelectorAll('paper-submenu')[1];
      sub3 = menu.querySelectorAll('paper-submenu')[2];
      collapse1 = Polymer.dom(sub1.root).querySelector('iron-collapse');
      collapse2 = Polymer.dom(sub2.root).querySelector('iron-collapse');
      collapse3 = Polymer.dom(sub3.root).querySelector('iron-collapse');
      trigger1 = sub1.querySelector('.menu-trigger');
      trigger2 = sub2.querySelector('.menu-trigger');
      trigger3 = sub3.querySelector('.menu-trigger');
    });
    test('selecting an item expands the submenu', function() {
      assert.isFalse(collapse1.opened);
      assert.isFalse(collapse2.opened);
      assert.isFalse(collapse3.opened);
      MockInteractions.tap(trigger1);
      assert.isTrue(collapse1.opened);
      assert.isFalse(collapse2.opened);
      assert.isFalse(collapse3.opened);
    });
```

Following the above example I tried the following:

```
test('Login Modal Opens', function(done) {
  expect(loginModal).to.exist;
  console.log(loginModal);
  console.dir(loginModal);
  expect(loginModal.opened).to.exist;

  assert.isFalse(loginModal.opened);

  btnLogin.click.bind(btnLogin);

  assert.isTrue(loginModal.opened);
});
```

Unfortunately I am getting `loginModal.opened` as undefined. `loginModal.toggle()` gives toggle is not a function error.

UPDATE:

I found that bind does not actually call the function. It only binds the `this` to a new location. So when I was doing `btnLogin.click.bind(btnLogin)` it was doing the binding so when I called `btnLogin.click()` it would have a binding to `btnLogin` rather than ... `btnLogin`. Therefore it would have been the same to just call `btnLogin.click()` without ever calling the `bind` function.

Now that this is figured out, I decided to mess with `call` instead of `bind` but again I only was binding the `this` to the same scope so that was no help. I then tried `btnLogin.click.call(element)` but it still gave me the error that this.$.loginModal.toggle is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, I don't know JS well

```
var el = Polymer.dom(element.root).querySelector('#btnLogin');
el.click().bind(el)();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you mind editing your answer to explain why this is needed? I do not have any idea what bind does. Thanks.

Comment: It's a basic principle of JavaScripts scope. `this` points to the environment where the function is executed, not where it's defined. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope. With `.bind()` you make the scope explicit to be the same as where it's defined. This is a fix https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. I would have suggested this instead if it were univerally available http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Thanks so much. That really helps. I was also looking it up and it seems that it is used all over the place. Guess I still have a lot to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: The bind allows me to bind the `this` but never calls the function. Call would allow me to call the function but I am still getting the same `this.$.loginModal.toggle` is not a function error.

Comment: Just adding `()` should do to call it after `bind()` - `el.click().bind(el)();`

Comment: Tried this and get the `this.$.loginModal.toggle` is not a function error. Also it seems that using `call` instead of `bind` would be more accurate to call the function right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call