# Confused by Javascript's this behaviour in a particular situation

Tags: javascript, this

I'm confused by what happens with *this* in this simple code:

```
function foo() {
    alert(this.a );
}

function doFoo(fn) {
    a = "local";
    fn();
}

var a = "global";

doFoo( foo );
```

From what I've learned, deFoo is the context object from which foo is called so the alert's message should be "local". That works, unless I declare *a* inside doFoo:

```
function doFoo(fn) {
    var a = "local";
    fn();
}
```

Now the alert message is "global". Can someone explain this to me? I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: `this` is crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to be considered:

1. `value` of this is determined by how `function` is called!
2. If `function` is called under the `global-context`, `this` refers to `window` (in browser)
3. If `variable` is not defined using keyword `var`, it is global variable.

In your example, `a` inside function `doFoo` refers to `window.a` which is `local`, overwritten when function is invoked.

```js
function foo() {
  alert(this.a);
}

function doFoo(fn) {
  console.log(window.a);
  a = "local"; //window.a is set to "local"
  fn();
}
var a = "global"; //window.a is "global"
doFoo(foo);

//Few logs to make it clear

console.log(window.doFoo);
console.log(window.a);
```

Comment: Why is the function being called under the global-context? I thought the context is determined by the call-site, and the call-site is doFoo. That is what confuses me.

Comment: @Rmm, when you say `var a = "global"` outside, then do  `a = "local"` inside the function, the global variable becomes `local`. If you add a `var`, in front it treats it as its own local `a` variable.

Comment: Yes this is a good explanation Rrmm you should accept this. By the way I added four examples on scope if you are still confused

Comment: I was assuming that doFoo worked as other objects and I could access the a variable inside it. If I declare a inside doFoo I was expecting 'this' to refer to that a, as doFoo is the call-side for foo.

My english is not perfect, sorry.

Comment: I tend to misunderstand things in crazy/silly ways. I thought I would be able to access 'a' as a property of the function.

I'm going to accept your answer as correct anyway. At least I identified the source of confusion.

Comment: Make sure you read @martriay's answer and mine as well, they might help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), so in your example `this` always refers to the global version of `a`, which gets overwritten in the first snippet.

As `var` defines a new variable in that scope, you're not modifying the global one, therefore printing `global` in the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First `a` is `global`, then we call `doFoo`, the `global` `a` is set to `local`.

We now call `fn()` which calls `foo()`, here `this` refers to the current execution context. Here `this` refers to the `global` scope.

Thus alerting `local`

Extra homework for you: Following similar logic, why does the following alert `global`?

```
var a = "global"

function thisA()
{
    var a = "local";
    fn();
}

function fn()
{
    alert(this.a);
}

thisA();
```

**Examples on Scope**

1.

```
var a = 3;
function myA()
{
    a = 2;
}

myA();
console.log(a); // 2
```

2.

```
var a = 3;
function myA()
{
    var a = 2;
}

myA();
console.log(a); // 3
```

3.

```
var a = 3;
function myA()
{
    var a = 2;
    myOtherA();
}

function myOtherA()
{
     a = 4;
}

myA();
console.log(a); // 4 since myOtherA() sets the global var a = 3 to 4, NOT myA();
```

4.

```
var a = 3;
function myA()
{
    var a = 2;
    function withinA()
    {
        a = 10;
    }
    withinA(); // changes var a = 2, to 10 NOT the outer a =3
}



myA();
console.log(a); // Still 3
```